# Plotting the components of a function that returns a list in different colors without redundant evaluations of the function

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning

I have a function `f` which takes a number as input, and returns a list of numbers (the length of the list is constant). `f` is hard to calculate (each evaluation takes a long time).

I want to plot the different components of `f` in *different colors*.

If I use this command:

```
Plot[f[x], {x, -2, 2}]
```

all the lines are drawn in the same color.
If I use this command:

```
Plot[{f[x][[1]], f[x][[2]], f[x][[3]]}, {x, -2, 2}]
```

(assuming the list has three components) the lines are drawn in different colors, but the function is called three times the necessary amount.

Note that this is a numeric function, it cannot be evaluated with a symbolic argument (i.e. the function definition begins with `f[x_Real]:=`), so there is no use in using `Evaluate` like in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1731/253).

Comment: The following code suggests that even `Plot[f[t],...]` evaluates `f` multiple times. `f[x_Real] := (i++; {x, x + 1, x + 2})` and `i = 0; Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 0]`, then `Print[i]`. The result is 31, not 10-ish. So, solutions just using `Plot` may not work as well.

Comment: @Yu-SungChang, sorry, I didn't see your comment. I wrote an answer which basically states the same. I give you +1 for your comment ;-)

Comment: Relevant SO question: "[How to select the “best” new point when sampling a near-parabolic function?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10861750/590388)"

Comment: Another related SO question: "[Telling Plot to style vector-valued black-box functions in Mathematica](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5597566/566639)"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At risk of stating the obvious, if you are willing to give up the adaptive sampling, exclusions, etc. of `Plot` you could use `ListLinePlot`:

```
f[x_?NumericQ] := x + Mod[x, {1, 2, 3}]

ListLinePlot[Transpose@Table[f[x], {x, 0, 10, 0.01}], PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Better I think is to [restyle](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17270/121) the `Graphics` data produced by plot, as Heike did for [Plotting piecewise function with distinct colors in each section](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1128/121) and which I refactored in my answer.  Applied here:

```
Module[{i = 1},
  Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Thick] /.
    x_Line :> {ColorData[1][i++], x}
]
```

[image]

---

Even nicer is Simon Woods' method which styles the plot while it is created, posted in answer to:

- [All curves in plot have the same style. Cannot be fixed with Evaluate[]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8637/121)

Also useful and very interesting is the solution by wxffles in the follow-up question:

- [An elegant way to plot a numeric function that returns a list, and have each element in a different color](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14597/121)

Comment: (+1) Because MMA uses adaptive sampling for *each* component of the function separately, memoizing doesn't usually save a lot of evaluation: the arguments used to plot the first component only slightly overlap the arguments used to plot the second component, etc.  (Sow the values of `x` with an `EvaluationMonitor` and then `ListPlot` them afterwards to see this.) Thus, this appears to be the only *really* effective workaround when good plotting arguments (values of $x$) are known in advance.

Comment: @whuber: My thoughts exactly. It seems that there is no way to make MMA's adaptive algorithm take into account all the values of a certain component that were already calculated as a result of evaluating `f` for the other components, and that's a shame. If evaluating `f` three (or more) times the necessary amount is more costly than the evaluations that the adaptive algorithm saves us (which is almost always the case for functions that take reasonably long to evaluate), this answer seems to be the best workaround. Accepted.

Comment: @Joe thanks for the Accept.  Sorry I didn't have something better for you.

Comment: +1 for the `Module[{i=0}...ColorData[1][i++]` alone! I'd have spent hours fiddling with MapIndexed's...

Answer (score 8):

Please consider the following simple example

```
i = 0;
f[x_?NumericQ] := {x^2, 2 x^2, x^2 + 1};
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 1}, EvaluationMonitor :> i++];
i

(* Out[30]= 471 *)
```

and now the same code for only the first component of `f`

```
i = 0;
Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}, EvaluationMonitor :> i++];
i

(* Out[33]= 157 *)
```

If you now recall, that $3\cdot 157 = 471$ you see that even in your `Plot[f[x],...]` call the function is called more often than one would naively expect. Therefore, I claim you can skip hard thinking about this issue.

Comment: You are correct. However, if I still want to plot all the components of `f` with a number of evaluations more close to 157, I need to use the approach described in [@Mr.Wizard's answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6446/253).

Answer (score 5):

You could memoize the function:

```
f[x_] := f[x] = x + Mod[x, {1, 2, 3}]

Plot[{f[x][[1]], f[x][[2]], f[x][[3]]}, {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you don't want to use memory globally for this or memoize for all calls to `f` you could make a copy:

```
Module[{g},
  g[x_] := g[x] = f[x];
  Plot[{g[x][[1]], g[x][[2]], g[x][[3]]}, {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Thick]
]
```

Comment: This is a nice workaround in case there is no way to address the problem directly, and it has the slight disadvantage of memory use. I would like to wait and see if someone comes up with a more direct approach.

Comment: @Joe please do wait; I'm hoping someone has a perfect solution.

Comment: From [@whuber's comment](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6442/plotting-the-components-of-a-function-that-returns-a-list-in-different-colors-wi#comment18355_6446), I learned that memoizing doesn't actually save function evaluations.

Comment: @Joe it *can* save evaluations, but not as many as reliably as I had thought.  `f[x_Real] := (i++; x + {Sin[x], Sqrt[x], Mod[x, 3]})`  then:  

`i = 0; 
Plot[{f[x][[1]], f[x][[2]], f[x][[3]]}, {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Thick]; i`
Compare: 
`i = 0; 
Module[{g}, g[x_] := g[x] = f[x];
 Plot[{g[x][[1]], g[x][[2]], g[x][[3]]}, {x, 0, 10}, 
  PlotStyle -> Thick]]; i`

Comment: You're right @Mr.Wizard, in your example memoizing saves evaluations, but it does not save _two thirds_ of the evaluations (I got 715 instead of 953). Of course we can't expect exactly two thirds, since there may be some overhead, by I think that even asymptotically we won't get two thirds.

Answer (score 1):

If your functions are continuous, you may use something like (naive example follows):

```
f[x_Real] := {2 x, 3 x};
Plot[f[x], {x, -2, 2}] /. {Hue[x__], Line[y__], Line[z__]} -> {Hue[x],
    Line[y], Hue[0, 1, 1], Line[z]}
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work well on my example, does it? (This was one of the first things I tried.)

Comment: I also tried to get really clever and use `Plot[{##&[], Sequence @@ f[x], ##&[]} . . .` but that's no good at all.  Maybe you can find a way to make it work.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Works only for continuous functions, as I said ...