# All curves in plot have the same style. Cannot be fixed with Evaluate[]

Tags: plotting, evaluation

Usually, when I plot multiple curves in Mathematica

```
Plot[{x,x^2,x^3},{x,0,1}]
```

they are given different colors.  However, if I try to construct a list inside the `Plot[]` function,

```
Plot[Table[x^n, {n, 1, 3}], {x, 0, 1}]
```

this doesn't work and all the curves come out the same color.  The standard advice (e.g. [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/difference-in-plot-when-using-evaluate-vs-when-not-using-evaluate), [here](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=497619) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/xSp_AzI30SU)), which works but which I don't fully understand, is to wrap the `Table[]` with an `Evaluate[]`:

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[x^n, {n, 1, 3}]], {x, 0, 1}]
```

or equivalently

```
f[x_,n_]:=x^n;
Plot[Evaluate[Table[f[x,n], {n, 1, 3}]], {x, 0, 1}]
```

This work in this case, because `f[x_]:=x^n` is a simple function.  However, suppose I have a complicated function `g[y]` which uses its argument `y` as a bound for an iterator:

```
g[y_] := Total[Table[1, {z, 1, Round[y + 1]}]]
```

Mathematica is not smart enough to recognize that this is equivalent to `g[y_]:=Round[y]+1`, and usually such a simplification will not be possible anyways.  `g[y]` cannot be evaluated symbolically, because of the iterator, although it's still plenty fast when given a machine number.  Then trying to plot various curves using a table constructed with `g[y]` without `Evaluate[]`

```
Plot[Table[g[x*n], {n, 1, 3}], {x, 0, 1}]
```

will make all the curves the same color.  Adding `Evaluate[]`

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[g[x*n], {n, 1, 3}]], {x, 0, 1}]
```

causes Mathematica to throw an error message about using a bad iterator. (`Table::iterb: "Iterator {z,1,Round[1+x]} does not have appropriate bounds`).

**Why, exactly, is `Evaluate[]` necessary in the simple case?** Is it true that `Plot[]` is interpreting the table as a multi-valued function?  Why?

**How can we achieve the same result in the complicated case where the technique fails?**

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`Evaluate` is necessary in this simple case because

> Plot has attribute HoldAll, and evaluates f only after assigning specific numerical values to x

and because `Plot` determines automatic styles based on the *unevaluated* form of `f`. When you call `Plot[Table[ ... ], ...]`, `Plot` looks at its first argument, `Table[ ... ]`, *without* evaluating it and notes that it has a length of 1, and it constructs style specifications based on that information. You can override this behavior of `Plot` by applying `Evaluate` to its first argument.

A simple way to accomplish what you want is to redefine `g` so that it wraps its output with `Hold`:

```
g[y_] := Hold@Total[Table[1, {z, 1, Round[y + 1]}]]
Plot[Evaluate@Table[g[n*x], {n, 1, 3}], {x, 0, 1}]
```

This works because the evaluated form of the first argument to `Plot` is now

```
{Hold[Total[Table[1, {z, 1, Round[x + 1]}]]], Hold[Total[Table[1, {z, 1, Round[2 x + 1]}]]], Hold[Total[Table[1, {z, 1, Round[3 x + 1]}]]]}
```

which does have a length of 3, and it doesn't produce an error because each of these three forms is held unevaluated until they are inside an environment that has a value bound to `x`.

Note that this variation

```
g[y_] := Total[Table[1, {z, 1, Round[y + 1]}]]
Plot[Evaluate@Table[Hold@g[n*x], {n, 1, 3}], {x, 0, 1}]
```

does not work, because it prevents `g` from being evaluated at all - we want `g` to be expanded with different values of `n`.

```
Evaluate@Table[Hold@g[n*x], {n, 1, 3}]
(* == {Hold[g[n x]], Hold[g[n x]], Hold[g[n x]]} *)
```

Comment: Thanks very much!  This is _very_ close to a perfect answer, except that it requires me to redefine `g[y]`.  Ideally we wouldn't need to do this because g might be a black box.  We could just define `h[y_]:=Hold[g[y]]` and use that, although this is still slightly awkward.

Comment: @Jess It's a good point, and I don't think there's a way around it with this approach. I'm glad you found the explanation clear, though!

Comment: I didn't know that `Plot` would work with expressions inside `Hold`!  Where is this documented?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard You know, that's a really good point - I found this through experimentation and didn't think about it too much, but it does mean that `Plot` must be using `ReleaseHold` at some point in the evaluation. And not all the plotting functions behave the same way: `DiscretePlot[Evaluate@Table[g[n*x], {n, 1, 3}], {x, 0, 1, 0.1}]` produces empty axes, for example. Just when you think you understand something...

Comment: I am switching this to the accepted answer almost 5 years after asking it because Simon's answer no longer works in Mathematica 11.

Answer (score 16):

You could use the `splitstyle` function from [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8199/proper-way-to-plot-a-single-function-in-two-different-styles) :

```
splitstyle[styles__]:=Module[{st=Directive/@{styles}},{{Last[st=RotateLeft@st],#}}&];

g[y_]:=Total[Table[1,{z,1,Round[y+1]}]];

Plot[Table[g[x*n],{n,1,3}],{x,0,1},PlotStyle->splitstyle[Red,Green,Blue]]
```

[image]

Or to use the standard colours:

```
Plot[Table[g[x*n],{n,1,3}],{x,0,1},PlotStyle->splitstyle@@ColorData[1]/@{1,2,3}]
```

[image]

(Note: This does not work in Mathematica 11.)

Comment: Brilliant!  I'm going to accept this because it doesn't require any modification of the primary argument of `Plot[]`, just the inclusion of an option.  (Of course, my decision has nothing to do with my spat with R.M about whether a fuller explanation of how `Plot[]` behaves would lead to a better answer...  :)  However, I'd like to point out to everyone that DGrady's answer is more compact, so if you don't mind modifying `g[y]` you should use his method.  Thanks!

Comment: +1; that's a really clever trick. Didn't see why it could be so useful until I looked at the question you linked to.

Comment: @Simon: Is it explained anywhere exactly what is happening when you set the `PlotStyle` option to a function rather than a directive?  This techniques doesn't seem to work for `DiscretePlot`.

Comment: @JessRiedel, I'm not sure if it's documented or not. I couldn't find it. Essentially `Plot` produces one or more `Line` primitives, and if you supply a function to `PlotStyle` it applies that function to each `Line`. For example you could use `PlotStyle->(Point@@#&)` to convert the lines to points. It appears that other plotting functions just ignore any `PlotStyle` which isn't a graphics directive.

Comment: Is there a way to get colors, when you don't know in advance how many series you'll have? (Say you are making a table of plots with different numbers of series.) Neither the `Evaluate` or `splitstyle` solutions seem to work for this case..

Comment: Doesn't appear to work in Mathematica 11.

Comment: I confirm that this no longer work in 11.1 on OSX Sierra.  Ugh.  Regretfully, I am switching the accepted answer to DGrady's.

Comment: @JessRiedel, I guess we should not be surprised. One of the hazards of using undocumented behaviour.

Answer (score 8):

Sadly the undocumented mechanism behind Simon's `splitstyle` no longer works in *Mathematica* 10.0 or 10.1.  Post-processing<sup>[(1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17250/121),[(2)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1128/121)</sup> remains an option as does [use of `ListPlot`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6442/121).  While pure post-processing is possible, in a bid to make this answer unique I shall instead define `styleSplitter` as a function that extracts the `PlotStyle` option from an unevaluated `Plot` expression.  If none is present the default for that plot type is taken from `Options`.

(This function can be viewed as a derivative of [xslittlegrass's `restylePlot2`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/59805/121) that pulls style information from the `Plot` expression itself.)

```
SetAttributes[styleSplitter, HoldFirst]

styleSplitter[plot : h_[___, op : OptionsPattern[]]] :=
 MapAt[
   ListLinePlot[Cases[Normal @ #, Line[x__] :> x, -3]
   , PlotRange -> Full
   , PlotStyle -> OptionValue[h, {op}, PlotStyle] ][[1]] &
   , plot
   , 1
 ]
```

Test:

```
g[y_] := Total[Table[1, {z, 1, Round[y + 1]}]];

Plot[
  Table[g[x*n], {n, 1, 3}], {x, 0, 1},
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Orange}
] // styleSplitter
```

[image]

Because styling is done by `ListLinePlot` itself automatic behaviors such as style cycling are preserved.

Answer (score 4):

For completeness, I'm going to give a solution which is hacky, but slightly less hacky than the one described by R.M in [a comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8637/all-curves-in-plot-have-the-same-style-cannot-be-fixed-with-evaluate#comment24731_8637) on the main post.  Here it is:

```
Show[
    Plot[g[x*#], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 5}, PlotStyle -> ColorData[1]@#]] &
     /@Table[n, {n, 1, 3}]
]
```

The advantage of this is that I don't need to modify `g[y]` and I also don't need to be quite as clever as Simon.  There are significant disadvantages though.  I had to add `PlotRange -> {0, 5}` because the default display range is now chosen by looking at just one of the curves.  An ideal solution would retain the ability of `Plot[]` to consider all curves at the same time and automatically choose a good default plot range.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this doesn't address the issue of all the plots being in the same style?

Comment: Oh, whoops.  I forgot the important but, where you use the index `n` to pull the style out of a list of directives.  Thanks for spotting that.

Comment: It's a bit cleaner to use `Range[1,3]` instead of `Table[n, {n, 1, 3}]`.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think changing `g` to evaluate to a [`Hold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hold) object (as in the accepted answer) is very convenient, and it relies on the undocumented (perhaps unintended) behavior of [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot) with [`Hold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hold) expressions. Instead, I would try one of the following approaches.

**Argument restriction**

Force `g` to only evaluate when given a numeric argument:

```
Clear[g]
g[y_?NumericQ] := Total[Table[1, {z, 1, Round[y + 1]}]]

Plot[Evaluate @ Table[g[n x], {n, 3}], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

**Inactive**

[`Inactivate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactivate) both [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot) and `g`, construct the desired plot expression, then [`Activate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Activate):

```
Clear[g]
g[y_] := Total[Table[1, {z, 1, Round[y + 1]}]]

Activate @ Inactive[Plot][Table[Inactive[g][n x], {n, 3}], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Another variation of this idea is:

```
Activate @ Inactivate[Plot[Table[g[n x], {n, 3}], {x, 0, 1}], Plot | g]
```

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case, the problem is with the definition of `g`

```
Clear[g]

g[y_] := Total@Table[1, {z, 1, Round[y + 1]}]
```

Note, for example, that `g[y] /. y -> 3.5` is not equivalent to `g[3.5]`

```
g[y] /. y -> 3.5
```

[image]

```
g[3.5]

(* 4 *)
```

Carl Woll showed a solution using `?NumericQ` to avoid evaluation unless the argument is numeric. However, for this case since `Total@Table[ ... ]` is equivalent to `Sum[ ... ]`, you could also redefine `g` as

```
Clear[g]

g[y_] := Sum[1, {z, 1, Round[y + 1]}]

Attributes[Sum]

(* {HoldAll, Protected, ReadProtected} *)
```

Since `Sum` has attribute `HoldAll`, now

```
(g[y] /. y -> 3.5) == g[3.5]

(* True *)

Manipulate[
 Plot[
  Evaluate@Table[g[x*n], {n, 1, 3}],
  {x, 0, 1}, PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", 0.25 {1, 3}],
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
  Exclusions -> exc],
 {{exc, None, Style["Exclusions", 12, Bold]}, {None, Automatic}}]
```

[image]