# How to Plot a function that returns multiple values?

Tags: plotting, evaluation

I have a function that returns multiple values, like this:

```
f[x_] := ( (*... something ... *); {y1, y2});
```

They are computed together, so there's absolutely no sense to split the function to two functions.

Now, I want to plot them both:

```
Plot[f[a], {a,0,1}]
```

Oops, the two graphs are drawn with the same style. Explicit style decaration (like `PlotStyle->{Red,Green}`) doesn't change the situation. The `Plot` routine doesn't recognize `f[a]` as two values. This is the main trouble. Well, the documentation has a cure for this:

```
Plot[Evaluate[f[a]], {a,0,1}]
```

It's OK... until it turns out that 1) numerical computation of `f` if *slow*, and 2) symbolic computation of `f` is *extremely slow*. In my case, there is a system of 10 linear equations. And this last expression evaluates `f` symbolically. Well, of course, I can forbid this by declaring `f` as `f[x_?NumericQ]`, but then the `Evaluate` operation becomes totally useless.

Why should I evaluate the whole function symbolically only to ensure that it returns two values? Is there another way to explain this fact to the `Plot` routine, so it would use different styles for the two graphs?

Well, actually, I know the answer:

```
Plot[{f[a][[1]], f[a][[2]]}, {a,0,1}]
```

But it is *ugly* and wasteful. It performs almost the same computations twice. It makes me feel uncomfortable. May be, there is a better solution?

Comment: I am certain this is a duplicate.  Let me find it.

Comment: Thank you. Of course, I tried to find someting like this before asking, but I failed.
Also, now I see in Related questions an elegant solution with `splitstyle` [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8637/all-curves-in-plot-have-the-same-style-cannot-be-fixed-with-evaluate?rq=1).

Comment: Also *very* similar: [(8637)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8637)

Comment: You're welcome.  Thanks for trying to find a Q&A first.

Comment: Reviewing the answers, Simon's `splitstyle` method in the second linked question is probably what you want; it's better than my methods in earlier question.