# Plot draws different curves in same colour even using Evaluate

Tags: plotting

I would like the solutions of `FindRoot` (using `NIntegrate` under  it) to be drawn in different colours by `Plot`, like in the last plot but without defining a separate function for each element in the solution list of `FindRoot`:

```
Clear[w, x, y, z, plt1, plt2, plt3, w1, w2]
w[x_?NumericQ] := {y, z} /. 
   FindRoot[{x*Exp[y] - y, 
     x*(Exp[z] - z)}, {{y, 0.45, 0, 1}, {z, 0.52, 0, 1}}];
plt1 = Plot[w[x], {x, 0, 1}, Evaluated -> True];
plt2 = Plot[Evaluate[w[x]], {x, 0, 1}];
w1[x_?NumericQ] := w[x][[1]]
w2[x_?NumericQ] := w[x][[2]]
plt3 = Plot[{w1[x], w2[x]}, {x, 0, 1}];
GraphicsRow[{plt1, plt2, plt3}]
```

Is there some simple plot option that does this? `Evaluate` as in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/plot-draws-list-of-curves-in-same-color-when-not-using-evaluate) does not seem to work for me.

Mathematica 11.3 on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46893) ?

Comment: The second equation is `x*(Exp[z] - z)==0` ? it seems that we can solve it directly.

Comment: @b.gates thank you - `Plot[{f[a][[1]], f[a][[2]]}, {a,0,1}]` is simple enough. @cvgmt yes, but the point is to illustrate plotting `FindRoot` results or some other vector valued function.

Comment: 1 up for `Evaluated`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

w[x_?NumericQ] := {y, z} /. 
   FindRoot[{x*Exp[y] - y, 
     x*(Exp[z] - z)}, {{y, 0.45, 0, 1}, {z, 0.52, 0, 1}}];
```

Evaluating `w[x]` with a symbolic input doesn't generate a `List` because `w[x]` is only defined for a numeric input.

```
Evaluate[w[x]]

(* w[x] *)
```

Since neither `Evaluate` nor the option `Evaluated -> True` has any effect on a symbolic `w[x]`, there is only one `PlotStyle`

You don't need to define separate functions, but you do need to explicitly list both parts of `w` for when it has numeric values.

```
Plot[{w[x][[1]], w[x][[2]]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[{"y", "z"}, {.2, .8}]] // Quiet
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy way to do this by making use of the function `SetOptions`. It allows one to modify the default options for any function. For the function `Plot`, its color is decided with the option `PlotStyle`. You can change this option to any other value globally using `SetOptions`.

```
SetOptions[Plot, PlotStyle :> RandomColor[]];
```

Note that I have used `RuleDelayed` instead of `Rule`. This is the key solution to your problem. When `RuleDelayed` is used, `RandomColor[]` is evaluated every time `Plot` is called, and thus the generated plot is of a different color. However, there are some rare cases when the subsequent output of `RandomColor[]` might be of a similar shade but I suppose you can figure out how to get around that.

So, after evaluating the above code, here is the output to your code:

[image: Output of Plot with different colors]

Comment: But the two curves are still the same colour in each of the 3 plots.