# Even with Evaluate[], Mathematica is plotting everything in the same color

Tags: plotting, evaluation

The code

```
evals[x_?NumericQ] := Eigenvalues[{{x^2, 2 x}, {x, 3 x^2}}];
Plot[Evaluate[evals[x]], {x, -1, 1}]
```

gives both eigenvalues in the same color.  I thought adding Evaluate[] was supposed to make them two different colors.  I've tried the setting Evaluated->True but that doesn't help.

Changing the second line to

```
Plot[{evals[x][[1]], evals[x][[2]]}, {x, -1, 1}]
```

works, but I figure in this case Mathematica is evaluating the function evals[x] twice for each x.  This is a toy example, and in my actual application the function corresponding to evals[] is extremely complicated and takes Mathematica quite a while to compute (which is why I have the ?NumericQ pattern test in the argument of evals), so I'd really prefer to have Mathematica only have to call evals[] once for each x, but still plot the two results in different colors.

Comment: Closely related, if not a duplicate: [(8637)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8637/121)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's assume you really can only evaluate your function `evals` for numeric values. Then the approach of using `Evaluate` or removing `?NumericQ` is not helping. For this situation, I see two possible solutions from the top of my head.

#### Using memoization suppress recalculation

```
evals[x_?NumericQ] := evals[x] = Eigenvalues[{{x^2, 2 x}, {x, 3 x^2}}];
Plot[{evals[x][[1]], evals[x][[2]]}, {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

With this, although it seems you call `evals[x]` two times inside `Plot`, it is actually only calculated once and for `evals[x][[2]]` you access the value again.

If you haven't heard of *memoization*, start reading [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2639/what-does-the-construct-fx-fx-mean) and check out the links [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8617/187).

#### Changing the colors of the plot *afterwards*

This is very simple too. You just plot `evals[x]`, getting the one-colored plot. Then, you give every `Line` primitive a different color. Here, I just create a variable `colNum` which is increased after each replacement. The standard color scheme should be `ColorData[97]` when I remember correctly:

```
gr = Plot[evals[x], {x, -1, 1}];
colNum = 1;
gr /. l_Line :> {ColorData[97, colNum++], l}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Apendix

Regarding your additional question

> I agree that memoization would help if you have complete control over the arguments at which *Mathematica* evaluates the functions. But when you use `Plot[]` or `Plot3D[]`, does *Mathematica* do some kind of adaptive evaluation where (say) it evaluates the function more densely when it's changing more quickly? In this case, *Mathematica* wouldn't necessarily evaluate the function at the same places, so it would need to call the function twice as often.

Your understanding is completely correct. Although it will save evaluations, it usually won't cut the number of function calls in half when you call `Plot` with automatic settings. The adaptive sampling you are talking about is the `MaxRecursion` option of `Plot`.

On the other hand, when you are setting `MaxRecursion->0` and steer the sampling quality with the `PlotPoints` options, the function will be sampled at exactly the same points. You can use the functions`Reap` and `Sow` to exactly check where and how often your definition is really evaluated if you like to investigate further.

> Do you happen to know the primitive graphic element for Plot3D[]? I'm actually plotting using Plot3D to plot a function of two variables, although for the sake of clarity I simplified this in my OP.

I won't hold you accountable for that because you did a great job by pinning down the problem and presenting a simplified version of it here.

Let me show you how you could have inspected this yourself. First, you make as always a very simplified `Plot3D` with two surfaces. Important is that you use very bad sampling settings, so that you don't have to deal with million of vertex points. In this specific case it means setting `MaxRecursion`, `PlotPoints` and removing all kind of meshes:

```
f[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := {Sin[x + y^2], Cos[x^2 + y]};
gr3d = Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 3, 
  MaxRecursion -> 0, Mesh -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now you take a close look at `InputForm[gr3d]`. What you can find out is that there is a longer style *header* that sets `EdgeForm`, lighting and color. What follows then is a `GraphicsGroup` consisting of two polygons.

When you compare this to a plot where you don't use `f` but the real expression, you see that all the styling header and the `GraphicsGroup` is done for each surface separately.

This is the base of your solution. Split the `GraphicsGroup` of several polygons into a version where each polygon gets its separate styling header. If you only want to change the color (and not the lighting and all), then this can be simplified:

Either you create a new `GraphicsGroup` with a leading color for each polygon

```
gr3d /. GraphicsGroup[polys:{_Polygon..}] :>
    ({RandomColor[],GraphicsGroup[{#}]}& /@ polys)
```

or you leave only *one* `GraphicsGroup` and prepend a color to each polygon. With this, you have to make sure that you create a list `{color, poly, color, poly, ...}` and not `{{color, poly}, {color, poly}, ...}` because `GraphicsGroup` expects a flat list of graphic primitives. I have enforced this by using `Flatten`:

```
gr3d /. GraphicsGroup[polys : {_Polygon ..}] :> 
  GraphicsGroup[Flatten[{RandomColor[], #} & /@ polys]]
```

Both solutions result in something like this

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks!  Two more quick questions:
(1) I agree that memoization would help if you have complete control over the arguments at which Mathematica evaluates the functions.  But when you use Plot[] or Plot3D[], does Mathematica do some kind of adaptive evaluation where (say) it evaluates the function more densely when it's changing more quickly?  In this case, Mathematica wouldn't necessarily evaluate the function at the same places, so it would need to call the function twice as often.

Comment: (2) Do you happen to know the primitive graphic element for Plot3D[]?  I'm actually plotting using Plot3D to plot a function of two variables, although for the sake of clarity I simplified this in my OP.

Comment: I see that Plot3D uses the graphics primitive Polygon, but when I try repeating your trick with Plot3D, I it looks weird.  Any ideas?

Comment: I added an *Appendix* to my answer and it hopefully answers all your questions accordingly.

Comment: Thanks!  I'd upvote your answer again if I could ... ;)

Answer (score 1):

To make `Plot` aware that it's a list:

```
evals[x_] = Eigenvalues[{{x^2, 2 x}, {x, 3 x^2}}]
Plot[Evaluate@evals@x, {x, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Colors are wrong - take a look a the plots of *each* component...

Comment: @ciao  `Plot[{x (2 x - Sqrt[2 + x^2]), x (2 x + Sqrt[2 + x^2])}, {x, -1, 1}]`

Comment: @ciao `If they are numeric, eigenvalues are sorted in order of decreasing absolute value.` ... if they are numeric ...

Comment: NVM - herp-a-derped and had not cleared something prior, so my results from eval were completely wrong...

Comment: @ciao A common Spanish saying "pasa en las mejores familias" (It happens also in the best families) ... or something like that :D

Comment: @Belisarius The crucial change is removing `x_?NumericQ`? It is not important whether one uses **Set** or **SetDelayed**. Is that correct?

Comment: @JackLaVigne Removing the `x_?NumericQ` allows Plot to symbolically evaluate its argument and "understand" that it is getting a list, yes

Comment: @belisarius, "happens to the best of us" is the corresponding English expression. Very close to the Spanish.

Comment: @PatrickStevens Thanks :)

Comment: As I mentioned in the OP, I need to keep the ?Numeric test in the argument of evals[], because the function has an extremely complicated analytic form and I want Mathematica to only evaluate it numerically.