# An elegant way to plot a numeric function that returns a list, and have each element in a different color

Tags: plotting, coding-style

I have a function that takes a numeric argument and returns a list of numbers. I want to plot each element of the list in a different color.

If I use this command,

```
Plot[f[x],{x,-1,1}]
```

all the elements are plotted in the same color. The function takes only a numeric argument (its definition is `f[x_?NumericQ]:=...`) so I can't use `Evaluate` like in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1731/253).

So far I've been using this command:

```
Plot[{f[x][[1]],f[x][[2]],f[x][[3]],f[x][[4]]},{x,-1,1}]
```

Which works fine (since the function evaluates very fast, I don't mind there are redundant evaluations here, see [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6442/253)). However this is not very elegant, and considering I have 16 elements to plot, it gets downright ugly.

**Is there a more elegant way to plot each element in a different color?**

Comment: How about `Plot[Evaluate[f[x]], ...]`?

Comment: @wxffles if you have `f[x_?NumericQ]:=...` (as indicated in the question) then that doesn't work.

Comment: [Identical question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597566/telling-plot-to-style-vector-valued-black-box-functions-in-mathematica) asked prior to mathematica.SE existence.

Comment: @Sasha - in the question you linked to the problem is to avoid redundant evaluations of the function, since it is expensive to evaluate (just like in [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6442/253), which is already mentioned above). In my question I don't mind redundant evaluations, my problem is coding style. These are two different issues.

Comment: The two highest voted answers below are **effectively duplicates** of answers to [(8637)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8637/121).  For this reason I argue that this question is a duplicate of that one.  Please vote to close if you agree or comment here if you do not.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
With[{n = Length@f[0]},
  Plot[Evaluate[Hold[f[x][[#]]] & /@ Range[n]], {x, 0, 1}]]
```

Comment: Interesting, `Hold` is invisible to `Plot`. +1

Comment: The essence of this method was previously posted here: [(8643)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8643/121)

Answer (score 7):

**PlotStyle settings as functions**

With @acl's example function

```
 f[x_?NumericQ] := {x, x^2, Sin@x, Cos@x, ArcTan[x]}

 i = 1; 
 Plot[f[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> ({Thick, {Red, Green, Blue, Orange,Brown}[[i++]], {##}} &)]
```

[image]

or, a variation:

```
i = 1;
Plot[f[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, PlotStyle -> 
 ({Thick, ColorData[5, "ColorList"][[;; Length[f[1]]]][[Mod[i++,Length[f[1]], 1]]], 
     Arrow @@@ {##}} &)]
```

[image]

**Update:  ... or use DownValues of the function:**

```
 Plot[Evaluate@DownValues[f][[All, 2]], {x, -Pi, Pi},  PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

Comment: This is very cool! But I think it fails if your functions get discontinuous. Try with `1/x}`. +1

Comment: @Rojo, this trick is still a new discovery for me, so it has many gaps. I think the case you mention can be adressed partially using something like `Mod[i++, Length[f[1]], 1]` instead of `i++` as the part index, bu then you get the two parts of `1/x` colored differently.

Comment: Using the downvalues isn't a robust solution, because it completely disregards additional caveats to the definitions. For example, plot: `Clear@f;f[x_?NumericQ] /; x < 0 := -{x, x^2, Sin@x, Cos@x, ArcTan[x]}
f[x_?NumericQ] := {x, x^2, Sin@x, Cos@x, ArcTan[x]}`

Comment: @rm-rf, oops --  It did feel too clean to be robust.(I was trying to remove the condition `?NumericQ` from the `DownValues` when I bumped into this.) thanks.

Comment: Incidentally this is essentially the same method Simon Woods posted here: [(8644)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8644)

Comment: Thank you @Mr.Wizard. Wasn't aware of that Q/A and the one linked there; just added two more Q/As to my favorites list.

Comment: Unfortunately like Simon's code this no longer works in version 10 or 10.1.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, all good undocumented things come to an end:(  Some in the same bag of tricks still work, e.g. `BoundaryStyle` and `MeshStyle` as in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/84151/125).

Answer (score 4):

Here is a variation of wxffles' method using [`Indexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Indexed.html) rather than undocumented behavior of `Hold` within `Plot`.  `Hold` still works in v10.1 but I think this is more likely to remain working; note that sadly kguler's answer no longer works due to changes in undocumented behavior.

```
f[x_?NumericQ] := {x, x^2, Sin@x, Cos@x, ArcTan[x]}

Plot[Indexed[f[x], #2] & ~MapIndexed~ f[0], {x, -4, 4}, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image]

Alternatives to `Indexed` are described here:

- [Prevent Part[] from trying to extract parts of symbolic expressions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14645/121)

Answer (score 2):

This is horrendous, but:

```
f[x_?NumericQ] := {x, x^2, Sin@x, Cos@x, ArcTan[x]}
length = Length@f[0];
Show@Table[
  Plot[f[x][[i]], {x, -1, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> {ColorData["SunsetColors"][i/length]}],
  {i, 1, length}
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

```
f[x_?NumericQ] := {x, x^2, Sin@x, Cos@x, ArcTan[x], ArcCos[x], 
  x^3/3, -x + 4/x}
```

And now

```
Block[{Plot, Part, x},
 Plot[f[x]~Part~# &~Array~8, {x, 0, 1}]
 ]
```

or

```
Plot[If[x \[Element] Reals, f[x][[#]]] &~Array~8, {x, 0, 1}, 
 Evaluated -> True]
```

Using what @wxffles just showed us in his answer

```
Plot[Hold@f[x][[#]] &~Array~8, {x, 0, 1}, Evaluated -> True]
```

Stealing @kguler's idea but impelmenting it more manually

```
Module[{i = 0}, 
 Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 1}] /. 
  l_Line :> {ColorData[1, "ColorList"][[++i]], l}]
```

Comment: Infix with part for no good reason

Answer (score -1):

You have to trick mma in thinking that your subsequent datapoints are separate datasets to be able to use `PlotStyle` with multiple colors.

Dummy data:

```
vals = Range[0, 2 \[Pi], 1/6 \[Pi]];
results = Sin[#] & /@ vals;
```

Getting this data in a the right format:

```
data = Partition[Transpose[{vals, results}], 1];
```

Then it's just making a rule for the colors and plot the whole thing:

```
ListPlot[data, 
 PlotStyle -> 
  MapThread[
   Rule, {Range[Length[vals]], 
    Table[ColorData["Crayola"][[3, 1,RandomInteger[{1, 134}]]],{Length[vals]}]}]]
```

Comment: By using `ListPlot` you're not taking advantage of the adaptive sampling algorithm of `Plot`.