# Prevent Part[] from trying to extract parts of symbolic expressions

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, functions, evaluation, symbolic

If you have a list, e.g.

```
{1, 2, 3}
```

then you can extract the $k$th part using `Part` (`list[[k]]`):

```
In[1]:= {1, 2, 3}[[2]]
Out[1]= 2
```

The problem is that if you provide a symbolic expression in the place of the list, `Part` will try to decompose it:

```
In[1]:= list[[2]]
Part::partd: Part specification list[[2]] is longer than depth of object.
Out[1]= list[[2]]
```

That is, **the issue occurs when the overall expression is evaluated before the value of `list` is known**. For example:

```
In[1]:= list[[2]] /. list -> {1, 2, 3}
Part::partd: Part specification list[[2]] is longer than depth of object.
Out[1]= 2
```

Although the final output is correct, this produces an annoying spurious error message.

It's even worse if `list` is a compound expression, because then `Part` will decompose it, unexpectedly changing its value. For example,

```
In[1]:= SinCos[x][[1]] /. SinCos -> (θ \[Function] {Sin@θ, Cos@θ})
Out[1]= x
```

[Wat.](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat)

#### Example

I commonly run into this when plotting one dimension of nested functions and data structures.

Suppose I have a function that generates a list of functions according to some parameters:

```
functions[x_Real, a_, b_, c_] := {Sin@x, Cos@x, Sin[a*x], Cos[b*x], Sin[c*x]};
```

Now I want to plot the first, third, and fourth functions in the list of functions with parameters $1,2,3$; in this case, $y = \sin(x), \sin(1 \cdot x), \cos(2 \cdot x)$. The obvious way is:

```
Plot[functions[x, 1, 2, 3][[#]]& /@ {1,3,4} // Evaluate, {x, 0, 5}]
```

(The `Evaluate` is needed to get `Plot` to treat the values as separate functions, so that they will be styled differently.) And Mathematica will dutifully plot... $y = x, 2, 3$:

```
{Plot[functions[x,1,2,3][[#]]&/@{1,3,4}//Unevaluated,{x,0,5}],
 Plot[functions[x,1,2,3][[#]]&/@{1,3,4}//Evaluate,{x,0,5}]}
```

[image: Wat]

#### Question

How do I prevent `Part[]` from trying to decompose symbolic expressions when it is evaluated?

I have a workaround below, but I'm interested in whether there's a better way to do it. Is there a standard built-in function that does what I'm looking for?

Comment: is [this Q/A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14597/125) related/useful? i.e. does `Plot[Evaluate[Hold[functions[x, 1, 2, 3][[#]]] & /@ {1, 3, 4}], {x, 0,  1}]` work for what you need to do?

Comment: Have you considered changing the order? For example: `(list /. list -> {1, 2, 3})[[2]]`

Comment: BTW, notice that deleting the `_Real` in `functions` will lead to an opposite result.

Comment: I'm sorry if the answer to the following question is obvious to you... Are you aware of the fact that a list `{a}` is as much a "symbolic" expression as is `list`? Or do you mean by symbolic that `AtomQ@list==True`?

Answer (score 7):

To outline the problem, if you write `Part[f[[x,2]],2]` with no rules for `f`, then part will just extract the contents of the "call" to `f`. Now for `Plot` called with evaluate, the expression evaluates fully before `x` is actually set, but in reality you only want it to partially evaluate and stop whenever `Part` attempts to extract a part of  a call to `f`.
To sketch it out, what you want is something like `(f[x,1,2,3]/.x->3)[[2]]` What you get is `f[x,1,2,3][[2]]/.x->3`.

If this behavior is something you want for a given `Head` of your own construction, it can be done with an `UpValue` definition switching over to a wrapper for part that only evaluates if the head is not the same as the one you wish to stop on:

```
 f /: Part[a_f, n_] := delayedPart[a, n, f]
 delayedPart[a_, n_, stopHead_] /; (Head[a] =!= stopHead) := Part[a, n]
```

So now, `f[x, 1, 2, 3][[2]]` becomes `delayedPart[f[x, 1, 2, 3], 2, f]` which evaluates as you want it to when x is given. So the difference from any regular function to this one is then if we add the definition for f:

```
 f[x_?NumericQ, a_, b_, c_] := {Sin@x, Cos@x, Sin[a*x], Cos[b*x], Sin[c*x]}
 g[VarX, 1, 2, 3][[1]] /. VarX -> 42 (* => 42 *)
 f[VarX, 1, 2, 3][[1]] /. VarX -> 42 (* => Sin[42] *)
```

Answer (score 6):

> #### Question
>
> How do I prevent `Part[]` from trying to decompose symbolic expressions when it is evaluated?

*Mathematica* 10 implements something like your `listPart` (with additional functionality): [`Indexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Indexed.html):

> Indexed can be used to indicate components of symbolic vectors,
>   matrices, tensors, etc.
>
> When expr is a list, Indexed[expr,i] gives expr[[i]].
>
> When expr is a list, Indexed[expr,{i,j,...}] gives
>   Indexed[expr[[i]],{j,...}].

For example:

```
expr = Indexed[q["x"], 1];

expr /. q["x"] -> {1, 2, 3}
```

> ```
> 1
> ```

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to allow for the extraction of multiple parts e.g. with `Span`.

Comment: In version 9, we can use ```Compile`GetElement```.

Answer (score 4):

One way is to define a new function that is the same as `Part`, except will only be evaluated if the parameter is a `List`:

```
ListPart[x_List, spec__] := x[[spec]];
```

Then, instead of using `list[[spec]]`, call `ListPart[list, spec]`. For example:

```
In[2]:= list[[2]]
Part::partd: Part specification list[[2]] is longer than depth of object.
Out[2]= list[[2]]
```

When `list` is not literally a `List`, `ListPart` does not evaluate...

```
In[3]:= ListPart[list, 2]
Out[3]= ListPart[list, 2]
```

... until the actual list value is available

```
In[4]:= ListPart[list, 2] /. list -> {1, 2, 3}
Out[4]= 2
```

as desired.

Disadvantage: `ListPart[list, 2]` is much more verbose than `list[[2]]`.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be two different issues here.

The first is with `Plot`: the expectation to use a definition for `functions[x_Real, a_, b_, c_] :=` and then get individually styled lines using `Part` and `Evaluate`.  This does not seem practical, as you specifically prevent symbolic evaluation with `_Real` (by the way, you may want `_?NumericQ`).  You could perhaps rewrite your function to allow symbolic evaluation which I believe would solve your other problem as well.

The second issue, and the topic of your question, may best be handled by changing the definition of `functions` (I'll use `f` for brevity) such that you always provide a part specification.  For example, I'll use the syntax `f[args][parts]`:

```
f[x_Real, a_, b_, c_][parts___] :=
  {Sin@x, Cos@x, Sin[a*x], Cos[b*x], Sin[c*x]}[[parts]];

f[0.3, 1, 2, 3][]

f[x, 1, 2, 3][{1, 3, 4}]

f[0.3, 1, 2, 3][{1, 3, 4}]
```

> ```
> {0.29552, 0.955336, 0.29552, 0.825336, 0.783327}
>
> f[x, 1, 2, 3][{1, 3, 4}]
>
> {0.29552, 0.29552, 0.825336}
> ```

This requires no auxiliary functions or definitions, no overloading of `Part`, and minimal keystrokes in use.  The only inconvenience is having to to add `[]` to each use of `f`.  You could turn the syntax around to `f[parts][args]` which, due to the order of evaluations in *Mathematica*, would allow using `f[args]` plainly, but you would lose the ability to put Attributes on `f` that would affect `args`, so I do not recommend it.

Another approach is a variation of jVincent's method:

```
f2[x_Real, a_, b_, c_] := {Sin@x, Cos@x, Sin[a*x], Cos[b*x], Sin[c*x]};

setPartHold[name_Symbol] :=
 Module[{part},
  name /: x_name[[spec__]] := part[x, spec];
  part[other : Except[_name], spec__] := other[[spec]]
 ]
```

Then call `setPartHold[f2]` once to produce this behavior:

```
f2[0.3, 1, 2, 3]

f2[x, 1, 2, 3][[{1, 3, 4}]]

f2[0.3, 1, 2, 3][[{1, 3, 4}]]
```

> ```
> {0.29552, 0.955336, 0.29552, 0.825336, 0.783327}
>
> part$584[f2[x, 1, 2, 3], {1, 3, 4}]
>
> {0.29552, 0.29552, 0.825336}
> ```

Note that the generated `part$xxx` function is active such that:

```
part$584[f2[x, 1, 2, 3], {1, 3, 4}] /. x -> 0.3
```

> ```
> {0.29552, 0.29552, 0.825336}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate solution I just worked out for a problem I am working on.  I have a function that calculates a vector of values.  In my problem, this function is rather time-consuming so I do not want to evaluate it more than I absolutely have to.  The toy version is

```
zz = Block[{a, b}, a = 3; b = 4; {a, b}]
```

Elsewhere in the notebook, I want to use these calculated values in a formula

```
z[[1]]/z[[2]] /. z -> zz
```

This correctly returns 3/4, but not before carping that the `Part` specification is longer than the depth of the object.  My solution is to write my first function to return a function that accesses elements of my list

```
zz = Block[{a, b, xx}, a = 3; b = 4; 
  Function[i, xx[[i]]] /. xx -> {a, b}]
```

where I have to use a little trickery to get `{a,b}` to evaluate in the `Function`. `zz` is now defined as

```
Function[i, {3, 4}[[i]]]
```

Now I can write an formula in terms of the array parts

```
z[1]/z[2] /. z -> zz
```

without generating an error from `Part`

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any points to comment on Daniel W's answer.

But here's how you write this

```
z[[1]]/z[[2]] /. z -> zz
```

to not generate any part errors

```
Indexed[HoldForm[z], 1]/Indexed[HoldForm[z], 2] /. HoldForm[z] -> zz
Out[1]=3/4
```