# Integrating a list of functions

Tags: list-manipulation, numerical-integration

For the purpose of this minimal example, let's say we have a list of functions, like this:

```
f[y_?NumericQ] := {NIntegrate[z*y, {z, 0, 1}], a y}
```

I want to integrate an expression involving `f`, say

```
NDSolve[{y'[t] == f[y[t]][[1]], y[0] == 1}, y[t], {t, 0, 5}]
```

Now, the problem is that this doesn't return the expected result, because `f[y[t]][[1]]` evaluates to `y[t]` inside the `NDSolve`.

How can this be done correctly?

Comment: I believe this is the related quesiton I was thinking of and it's not a duplicate, but perhaps interesting nevertheless: [(11772)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11772/121)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [14645](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14645/prevent-part-from-trying-to-extract-parts-of-symbolic-expressions)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can include the part extraction as an argument of your function, perhaps as a `SubValues` definition:

```
ClearAll[f]

f[y_?NumericQ][part_] := {NIntegrate[z*y, {z, 0, 1}], a y}[[part]]

NDSolve[{y'[t] == f[y[t]][1], y[0] == 1}, y[t], {t, 0, 5}]
```

> ```
> {{y[t]->InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,5.}},<>][t]}}
> ```

Or, inside the primary body as an optional argument:

```
ClearAll[f]

f[y_?NumericQ, part_: All] := {NIntegrate[z*y, {z, 0, 1}], a y}[[part]]

NDSolve[{y'[t] == f[y[t], 1], y[0] == 1}, y[t], {t, 0, 5}]
```

This second method returns both values by default:

```
f[3.6]
```

> ```
> {1.8, 3.6 a}
> ```

---

An alternative that comes to mind is to use a custom `Part` function that won't trigger when it should not, e.g.:

```
ClearAll[f]
listPart[x_List, part__] := x[[part]]

f[y_?NumericQ] := {NIntegrate[z*y, {z, 0, 1}], a y}

NDSolve[{y'[t] == f[y[t]] ~listPart~ 1, y[0] == 1}, y[t], {t, 0, 5}]
```

Answer (score 0):

*Mathematica* 10 introduces something like `listPart`, with additional functionality, in [`Indexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Indexed.html):

> Indexed can be used to indicate components of symbolic vectors,
>   matrices, tensors, etc.
>
> When expr is a list, Indexed[expr,i] gives expr[[i]].
>
> When expr is a list, Indexed[expr,{i,j,...}] gives
>   Indexed[expr[[i]],{j,...}].

`Indexed` can be used instead of `Part` for single-element extraction (at any level).

Applied to the case at hand:

```
f[y_?NumericQ] := {NIntegrate[z*y, {z, 0, 1}], a y}

NDSolve[{y'[t] == Indexed[f[y[t]], 1], y[0] == 1}, y[t], {t, 0, 5}]
```

> ```
> {{y[t] -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 5.}}, <>][t]}}
> ```