# Passing f[x][[1]] to FindRoot

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, syntax

`FindRoot` seems to fail for most examples of the form

```
f[x_?NumericQ] := {x - 3 , x^3};
FindRoot[f[x][[1]], {x, 3}]
```

> ```
> {x -> 0.}
> ```

I expected `{x -> 3}`. The same occurs for `FindMinimum`, even for this case

```
FindMinimum[{f[x][[1]], x > 1}, {x, 3}]
```

> ```
> {1., {x -> 1.}}
> ```

What is going here guys? I'm using *Mathematica* 9.0.1.0 for Linux x86.

Comment: Related: [Integrating a list of functions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21662/integrating-a-list-of-functions/21663)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take [parts of expressions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PartsOfExpressions.html) just like you can with a list, so what happens here is:

```
Clear[f];
f[x][[1]]
(* x *)

(* Same thing happens with NumericQ since then f[x] doesn't evaluate *)
f[x_?NumericQ] := 1
f[x][[1]]
(* x *)
```

To get around this you need to make sure [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html) doesn't try to extract until it has the result of `f`, for instance like:

```
f[x_?NumericQ] := {x - 3, x^3}
g[x_?NumericQ, i_Integer] := f[x][[i]]
FindRoot[g[x,1], {x,987}]
(* {x -> 3. } *)

(* Or a bit more general: *)
nPart[v_List, p__] := With[{res = v[[p]]}, res /; NumericQ[res]]
FindRoot[nPart[f[x], 1], {x, 987}]
(* {x -> 3. } *)
```

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. Great answer.