# NIntegrate receiving a function with NumericQ which returns a list

Tags: list-manipulation, numerical-integration, numerics

Can some one please explain why

```
 f[x_?NumericQ] := {{x, 2}, {-1, -x}}
 NIntegrate[ f[S], {S, 0, 1}]
 (*->NIntegrate::inum: Integrand f[S] is not numerical at {S} = {0.00795732}. >> *)
```

A possible work around is

```
f1[x_?NumericQ][part__] := {{x, 2}, {-1, -x}}[[part]]
```

then use something like

```
ArrayReshape[ NIntegrate[ f1[S][#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@  {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}}, {S, 0, 1}], {2, 2}]
```

but this is ugly, and does it evaluate `f1` four times?

This type of problem appears when `f` involves matrix calculations and a numerical component (can not be done symbolically). This way, one is always forced to calculate all elements, even if you need only one. So it would advantages if `NIntegrate` did not evaluate `f` more times than necessary.

I thank any assistance in advance.

Possible related questions [1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16694/numericq-equivalent-for-lists), [2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14645/prevent-part-from-trying-to-extract-parts-of-symbolic-expressions) and [3](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21662/integrating-a-list-of-functions/21663#21663).

Comment: Am I the only one to see a missing } over there?

Comment: Haha yes a `}` was missing, but that doesn't change the  question.

Comment: I can't think out a work-around with the existence of `_?NumericQ`, but what do you really want? Just a explanation for the failure? A numerical integration without symbolic processing for a list of expressions? Or something else?

Comment: Hi @xzczd, basically yes, I want "A numerical integration without symbolic processing for a list". I've added a short explanation at the end of the post. Thanks for thinking on this. Cheers

Comment: Er… Sorry but I can't understand the added explanation very well 囧, and I just noticed that the `listPart` isn't actually used in your work-around… BTW, have you considered something like `Method->{Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing"->False"}`?

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but it appears to me that `NIntegrate` wants to integrate a list/matrix componentwise, by mapping `NIntegrate` onto the parts.  It might not integrate matrices as such.

Comment: @xzczd sorry, defining `listPart` was useless, I've removed it.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes I could map `NIntegrate` onto the parts, but would that not be very inefficient? For to accesse each component, all components are calculated. Cheers

Comment: @ArturGower I would think so, unless each part was an `InterpolatingFunction` or something similar and independently accessible.  I hope was clear earlier: `NIntegrate` tries to map itself onto the parts, not that you should.  The problem seems to arise from the fact that `f[1]` is an array and `f[S]` is not.  It seems to do just those two evaluations (in that order) and bails out -- with a misleading error message, if I'm right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps someone who knows can address the actual limitations of `NIntegrate`.  It seems to me that, despite a couple of examples in the documentation, `NIntegrate` does not integrate vectors, matrices, and other arrays as arrays per se.  Instead it integrates their components individually, effectively mapping `NIntegrate` onto the components.

The main evidence is the following.  If I make `f[S]` return four component expressions, `NIntegrate` gets mapped onto each one.  Note the `f[1]` is evaluated first, which would tell `NIntegrate` that the value of `f` is a 2x2 array.  In the OP's code, `f[S]` is a single expression, which `NIntegrate` does not like.

```
ff[x_?NumericQ] := {{x, 2}, {-1, -x}};
ff[x_] = Array[ff[x, ##] &, {2, 2}];
f[x_] := (Print[ff@x]; ff[x]);
NIntegrate[f[S], {S, 0, 1}]
```

> {{1, 2}, {-1, -1}}
>
> {{ff[S,1,1], ff[S,1,2]}, {ff[S,2,1], ff[S,2,2]}}
>
> NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand ff[S,1,1] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,1}}. >>
>   ...
>   General::stop: Further output of NIntegrate::inumr will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

```
(* {{NIntegrate[ff[S, 1, 1], {S, 0, 1}], 
     NIntegrate[ff[S, 1, 2], {S, 0, 1}]},
    {NIntegrate[ff[S, 2, 1], {S, 0, 1}],
     NIntegrate[ff[S, 2, 2], {S, 0, 1}]}} *)
```

I don't claim this is conclusive evidence, but I have not found a way to use `NIntegrate` to integrate the OP's `f`.

***Workaround***

`NIntegrate` and `NDSolve` are not equivalent, not in functionality, speed, or accuracy.  In this case, `NDSolve` can address the OP's problem on it's own terms -- that is, it can integrate a matrix differential equation in terms of matrices.

```
ClearAll[a, f];
f[x_?NumericQ] := {{x, 2}, {-1, -x}};

asol = NDSolveValue[{a'[t] == f[t], a[0] == {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}}, a, {t, 0, 1}];
asol[1]

(* {{0.5, 2.}, {-1., -0.5}} *)
```

It seems (to me) that if the component functions of the matrix function `f` could be integrated separately, then `NIntegrate` is likely to do a superior job finding the integrals.  But when the components cannot be integrated independently, one can use `NDSolve`.