# How to make integrals of interpolated matrices constructed by other interpolated quantities?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, interpolation

I have the following code producing an interpolated unitary matrix:

```
H[t_] := PauliMatrix[3] + Cos[t]*PauliMatrix[1];

sol = First[NDSolve[{I*D[matU[s],s] == H[s].matU[s],matU[0] == IdentityMatrix[2]}, matU, {s, 0, 20}]];

mU = matU /. sol;
```

This produces the unitary matrix `mU` which I can use as a function. For example, writing `mU[4]` gives a matrix.
However, if I want to integrate this, for example writing `NIntegrate[mU[t], {t, 1, 5}]` it does not work. It says

> NIntegrate: Integrand InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,20.}},{5,3,1,{282},{4},0,0,0,0,Automatic,<<3>>},{{<<1>>}},{{{{1. +0. I,0. +0. I},{0. +0. I,1. +0. I}},{{0. -1. I,0. -1. I},{0. -1. I,0. +1. I}}},<<9>>,<<272>>},{Automatic}][t] is not numerical at {t} = {1.00015}.

The first question is: how do I do this integral?

Second part:
I use the unitary matrix to define time-dependent vectors as follows,

```
vec = {0, 1};
vect[t_] := mU[t].vec;
ρ[t_] := Outer[Times, vect[t], vect[t]\[Conjugate]];
```

Then, I try to integrate using `NIntegrate[ρ[t], {t, 1, 5}]` and I get two different errors:

> Outer: Heads Conjugate and Dot at positions 3 and 2 are expected to be the same.

> NIntegrate: Integrand Outer[Times,<<1>>,Conjugate[InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,20.}},{5,3,1,{282},{4},0,0,0,0,Automatic,<<3>>},{{0.,<<9>>,<<272>>}},{{{{<<2>>},{<<2>>}},{{<<2>>},{<<2>>}}},{{{<<2>>},{<<2>>}},{{<<2>>},{<<2>>}}},<<8>>,<<272>>},{Automatic}][t].{0,1}]] is not numerical at {t} = {1.00015}.

Why do I get these errors and how can I avoid them?

Thanks everybody for the help!

**Edit1:**
When `Integrate` is directly applied to the original interpolated matrix it seems to work. Therefore, the value of `NIntegrate[ρ[t], {t, 1, 5}]` can be obtained as follows.
First, we make Mathematica numerically solve the differential equation for `ρ`:

```
solρ = First[NDSolve[{I*D[ρS[s], s] == 
      H[s].ρS[s] - ρS[s].H[s], ρS[0] == 
      Outer[Times, vec, vec]}, ρS, {s, 0, 20}]];
ρt = ρS /.solρ;
```

Then, we can integrate it using `Integrate[ρt[t], {t, 1, 5}]`.
However, if we try to compute `Integrate[Sin[t]*ρt[t], {t, 1, 5}]` or even `Integrate[Sin[t]+ρt[t], {t, 1, 5}]` we do not get any number as output (but we also do not get error messages).

The same numerical result can be obtained with the following code which follows the one given in an answer:

```
vect2[t_, i_] := mU[t][[i, 2]];
ρ2[t_, i_, j_] := vect2[t, i]*vect2[t, j]\[Conjugate];
Table[NIntegrate[ρ2[t, i, j], {t, 1, 5}], {i, 2}, {j, 2}]
```

When using this, Mathematica does complain a bit but arrives at the same result up to 10^(-7).
Moreover, with this code we can calculate the following `Table[NIntegrate[Sin[t]*ρ2[t, i, j], {t, 1, 5}], {i, 2}, {j, 2}]`.
However, this code seems quite a workaround, which I would prefer to avoid in more complex situations.

Comment: Try: `Integrate[mU[t], {t, 1, 5}]` It looks like Integrate can deal with matrices, but NIntegrate can not.

Comment: Thanks! It does work on `mU[t]` but still does not work for `\[Rho][t]`.

Comment: Related (to `NIntegrate` on arrays):  [(34554)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34554), [(126001)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/126001)

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a problem with NIntegrate and matrices (although for simple matrices NIntegrate works.).

You may try calculating the different matrix elements separately:

```
H[t_] := PauliMatrix[3] + Cos[t]*PauliMatrix[1];

sol = First[
   NDSolve[{I*D[matU[s], s] == H[s] . matU[s], 
     matU[0] == IdentityMatrix[2]}, matU, {s, 0, 20}]];

mU = matU /. sol;
vect[t_] := mU[t][[ All,2]];
Clear[\[Rho]];
\[Rho][t_?NumericQ, i_, j_] := vect[t][[i]] Conjugate[vect[t]][[j]];
```

With this we can calculate the matrix:

```
Table[NIntegrate[\[Rho][t, i, j], {t, 1, 5}] , {i, 2}, {j, 2}]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you very for the answer! Hi think that it should be `vect[t_] := mU[t][[All, 2]];`. By doing this, I get the same result as with an even more direct method.
However, this seems a work-around that makes things cumbersome if I want to further manipulate things. I'm adding an edit to my question.

Comment: You are right, I made the correction.

Answer (score 0):

[`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate) is expecting the integrand to evaluate to a number, not a matrix, which is why it doesn't work.

Instead of using [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate), why don't you just augment your original differential equation? For example:

```
{int, m} = NDSolveValue[
    {
        I matU'[s] == H[s] . matU[s], matU[0] == IdentityMatrix[2],
        i'[s] == matU[s], i[0] == {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
    },
    {i, matU},
    {s, 0, 20}
];
```

Then:

```
int[5] - int[1]
```

> {{-0.00620054 + 0.650422 I, -0.925243 - 0.481496 I}, {0.925243 -
> 0.481496 I, -0.00620054 - 0.650422 I}}

which agrees with:

```
Integrate[m[s], {s, 1, 5}]
```

> {{-0.00620039 + 0.650422 I, -0.925243 - 0.481496 I}, {0.925243 -
> 0.481496 I, -0.00620039 - 0.650422 I}}

Similarly, for your ρ example, you can do:

```
{int, sinint, ρ} = NDSolveValue[
    {
        I ρS'[s] == H[s] . ρS[s] - ρS[s] . H[s], ρS[0] == Outer[Times, vec, vec],
        i'[s] == ρS[s], i[0] == {{0, 0}, {0, 0}},
        isin'[s] == Sin[s] ρS[s], isin[0] == {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
    },
    {i, isin, ρS},
    {s, 0, 20}
];
```

Then:

```
int[5] - int[1]
```

> {{1.43151 + 0. I, 0.147931 + 0.453175 I}, {0.147931 - 0.453175 I,
> 2.56849 + 0. I}}

which agrees with Daniel's answer, while:

```
sinint[5] - sinint[1]
```

> {{0.499208 + 0. I, -0.231473 + 0.138672 I}, {-0.231473 -
> 0.138672 I, -0.242568 + 0. I}}

gives the value of:

```
Integrate[Sin[t] ρ[t], {t, 1, 5}]
```

Note that using [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue) is much more convenient than using [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve).