# Numerically integrating a list-valued function

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics

I want to `NIntegrate` a `List` valued function `foo[x]` which is only defined for numerical arguments `x`.
Here is a simple toy example:

```
foo[x_?NumericQ] := {x^2, x^3};
NIntegrate[foo[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

It gives the following error

> ```
> NIntegrate::inum: Integrand foo[x] is not numerical at {x} = {0.00795732}. >>
> NIntegrate::inum: Integrand foo[x] is not numerical at {x} = {0.00795732}. >>.
> ```

Note that the symbolic definition `fooS` works fine:

```
fooS[x_] := {x^2, x^3};
NIntegrate[fooS[x], {x, 0, 1}]
(*{0.333333, 0.25}*)
```

What causes the error?

It seems to be crucial that the function `foo` is `List` valued.
When I `NIntegrate` each component separatly, the error does not occur:

```
foo1[x_?NumericQ] := foo[x][[1]];
foo2[x_?NumericQ] := foo[x][[2]];
{NIntegrate[foo1[x], {x, 0, 1}], NIntegrate[foo2[x], {x, 0, 1}]}
(*{0.333333, 0.25}*)
```

and even

```
NIntegrate[{#1, #2} & @@ {foo1[x], foo2[x]}, {x, 0, 1}]
(*{0.333333, 0.25}*)
```

Comment: Thanks for the Accept, but I suggest that you wait at least 24 hours to let everyone around the world have a chance to answer.  You may like a different answer more if you don't discourage someone from posting by making the issue appear concluded.

Comment: Related: [(11772)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11772), [(14645)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14645), [(21662)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21662), and even: [(1731)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1731)

Comment: Everyone who voted for my answer or Jens' answer should vote for Michael's [earlier answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/34859/121) as it already covered both aspects of the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems like a bug, or at least a "glitch" in `NIntegrate`.  I believe that it expects the evaluated structure of the integrand to match when given symbolic and numeric input.  I imagine that it looks at the structure of the output of `foo[x]` and then sets up the rest of the computation based on that; when it then get a `List` output from e.g. `foo[0]` it fails to match the expected pattern and errors.

By providing an integrand that is explicitly a two element list in its evaluated (symbolic) form we eliminate the error:

```
foo[x_?NumericQ] := {x^2, x^3};

NIntegrate[{Indexed[foo[x], 1], Indexed[foo[x], 2]}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

> ```
> {0.333333, 0.25}
> ```

Note that unlike `Part` [`Indexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Indexed.html) will remain unevaluated until its first argument is a `List`.

The evaluated symbolic form:

```
{Indexed[foo[x], 1], Indexed[foo[x], 2]}
```

> ```
> {Indexed[foo[x], {1}], Indexed[foo[x], {2}]}
> ```

Comment: note this is evaluating each of the  list expressions twice for each x .. so it illustrates the issue but isn't likely a good approach for performance reasons.

Comment: that issue is somewhat avoided if you do : `foo[x_?NumericQ] :=foo[x]= {x^2, x^3}` ( though not entirely in case `NIntegrate` wants to evaluate the expressions at different points )

Comment: @george2079 Good point!  I meant this answer as an illustration of my understanding of the cause, not a general purpose solution.

Answer (score 6):

The explanation was already delivered by Mr.Wizard, but I would like to add that there is a similar capability to the `Indexed` approach already built in to `NDSolve` or `NDSolveValue`. So we can leverage `NDSolve` instead of `NIntegrate` as follows:

```
foo[x_?NumericQ] := {x^2, x^3};
NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == foo[x], y[0] == {0, 0}}, y, {x, 0, 1}][1]
(* ==> {0.333333, 0.25} *)
```

Here, the initial condition `y[0] == {0, 0}` tells *Mathematica* that the integral `y[x]` is a vector function.

This approach can also be adapted for version 8 by using `NDSolve`. It doesn't suffer from the performance hit due to double evaluation of the integrand as in Mr Wizard's answer.

Another side-benefit is that the result of `NDSolveValue` yields a *function* that can give you the value of the integral for all *intermediate* values between `x=0` and `x=1`, just by replacing the argument `[1]` at the end of the command by a different argument.

**Edit**

What I describe as a potential advantage of `NDSolve` could also become a disadvantage, if you're *really* only interested in the end point of the integration interval and don't want to store the intermediate values of the integral `y[x]`. As Alexey mentions in the comment, the result of `NDSolve` will remain unchanged if we replace the *specification* of the integration domain by the apparently meaningless `{1, 1}`, because the integration will still be done over the interval `{0, 1}` if we leave the initial condition `y[0] == {0, 0}` unchanged. However, the storage requirement for the function `y[x]` over the domain `{1, 1}` is potentially much reduced.

Comment: (+1) I can add that if the value at only one point is needed one can get a bit better performance and [small memory requirements](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/3sr5Er6Kvqo/npH21yBBP5UJ) by replacing `{x, 0, 1}` with `{x, 1, 1}`: `NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == foo[x], y[0] == {0, 0}}, y, {x, 1, 1}][1]`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thanks, that's an important point - I'll mention it in my answer.

Comment: Jens, I believe this question is a duplicate.  Will your method apply to this example as well?: [(34554)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34554)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I believe this is equivalent to the "workaround" in my answer to that question.

Comment: @Michael I missed that.  Looks like you covered everything there already.  Now your answer just needs more votes. :-)

Comment: @MichaelE2 I knew this idea must have been pointed out before - just didn't think to check (upvoted yours now).

Comment: @Jens I thought I had answered such a question, but Mr.Wizard is the one who found it first.

Comment: @MichaelE2 That's my excuse for having answered here initially: I thought if Mr.Wizard hasn't found a duplicate it can't be one...

Answer (score 2):

I'd argue you should reformulate your function to avoid the issue -- however if a straightforward quadrature scheme will work for you (ie. you don't need adaptive schemes  etc ) you can do a direct evaluation:

Simpsons rule for example:

```
 foo[x_?NumericQ] := ({x^2, x^3});
 np = 99;(*assumed odd for simpsons rule*)
 a = 0;
 b = 1;
 wt = (b - a)/(3 (np - 1)) Join[{1}, 
      Flatten@ConstantArray[{4, 2}, (np - 1)/2 - 1], {4, 1}] // N;
 x = a + (b - a) (Range[0, np - 1] /(np - 1)) // N;
 wt.# & /@ Transpose[ foo /@ x ]
```

> {0.333333, 0.25}

Note that if you do need advanced functionality of `NIntegrate` you likely want it to work independently on each expression.

Comment: Lower level solutions are always of value. +1

Comment: Consider moving (reposting, then deleting) your answer here: [(34554)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34554)  I believe it is equally applicable, and it would be better placed in a non-duplicate Q&A.