# FindFit “is not a real number” error when fitting a parametric function to the data

Tags: fitting

I am using Mathematica's FindFit function to fit a parametric solution to my data and I am getting the error

```
FindFit::nrnum: The function value [complicated expression] is not a real number at {ka,kd,beta} = {0.7,0.1,0.1}
```

he initial guesses of the parameters {ka=0.7,kd=0.1,beta=0.1} are very close to the values I used to mock up the data, and I can't figure out where I am going wrong. I posted a similar version of this question on stack exchange but didn't get any response.

First I use the ParametricNDSolveValue function to parametrically solve two coupled first order differential equations for the functions 'a[t]' and 'b[t]' with parameters ka, kd, and beta:

```
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{D[a[t], t] == -kd*a[t] + ka*(1 - a[t] - b[t]), a[0] == ka/(ka + kd), 
  D[b[t], t] == -kd*b[t] + ka*(1 - Exp[-beta*t]) (1 - a[t] - b[t]), b[0] == 0 }, {a, b}, 
  {t, 0, 20}, {ka, kd, beta}]
```

I can extract the solution for `a[t]` for `ka=0.7, kd=0.1, beta=0.1` by using:

```
y1 = sol[0.7, 0.1, 0.1][[1]]
```

Plotting `y1` as a function of `t` gives the expected curve:

```
Plot[y1[t], {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Then I create a data table eyeballing the values from the above plot:

```
dataA = {{0, 0.87}, {5, 0.84}, {10, 0.75}, {15, 0.68}, {20, 0.62}}
```

Finally to test `FindFit`, I use `FindFit` with `sol[ka, kd, beta][[1]][t]` to fit the data giving the same initial values for `ka`, `kd`, and `beta` that I used to generate the above data:

```
fit = FindFit[dataA, sol[ka, kd, beta][[1]][t], {{ka, 0.7}, {kd, 0.1}, {beta, 0.1}}, t]
```

At which point I get the error:

```
FindFit::nrnum: "The function value 1/2\ ((-0.87+Abs[0.7[0.]])^2+(-0.84+Abs[0.7[5.]])^2+(-0.75+Abs[0.7[10.]])^2+(-0.68+Abs[0.7[15.]])^2+(-0.62+Abs[0.7[20.]])^2) is not a real number at {ka,kd,beta} = {0.7,0.1,0.1}."
```

I tried using `Abs[sol[ka, kd, beta][[1]][t]]` in `FindFit`, that didn't work. Then I tried adding constraints:

```
fit = FindFit[dataA, {Abs[sol[ka, kd, beta][[1]][t]], {ka > 0, kd > 0, 
  beta > 0}}, {{ka, 0.7}, {kd, 0.1}, {beta, 0.1}}, t]
```

And that failed too.

Any clues what is wrong with my code? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Take a close look at your error output message. Your variable substitution is problematic and you end up with terms like Abs[0.7[5.]] repeatedly. 0.7 is not a function and cannot be addressed as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{D[a[t], t] == -kd*a[t] + ka*(1 - a[t] - b[t]), a[0] == ka/(ka + kd), 
                        D[b[t], t] == -kd*b[t] + ka*(1 - Exp[-beta*t]) (1 - a[t] - b[t]), 
                        b[0] == 0}, {a, b}, {t, 0, 20}, {ka, kd, beta}];

dataA = {{0, 0.87}, {5, 0.84}, {10, 0.75}, {15, 0.68}, {20, 0.62}};

fit = FindFit[dataA, a[ka, kd, beta][t] /. sol, {{ka, 0.7}, {kd, 0.1}, {beta, 0.1}}, t]

 (* {ka -> 0.932926, kd -> 0.136649, beta -> 0.0603393} *)

Plot[{a[.7, .1, .1][t] /. sol, a[ka, kd, beta][t] /. fit /. sol}, {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1 But could you explain why the result of 'ParametricNDSolveValue' isn't working here?

Comment: @Matariki I haven't tried it :)

Comment: @belisarius Thanks a lot, this worked! I think my syntax of finding "the solution for a[t]" from ParametricNDSolveValue is incorrect, i.e. it is incorrect to use `sol[ka, kd, beta][[1]][t]` in FindFit, but I don't know why. Also, an excellent post by @Oleksandr R. on the question of simultaneously fitting multiple datasets with a parametric solution of coupled differential equations can be found here: [link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28461/how-to-fit-3-data-sets-to-a-model-of-4-differential-equations)

Comment: @Sam Glad to hear it helped

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `sol[ka, kd, beta][[1]][t]` evaluates to
`ka[t]` before numeric values are substituted for the parameters.  You need to prevent evaluation of `[[1]]` until after `sol` has evaluated to a list of solutions.

Thanks to [Mr.Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard) for pointing out [`Indexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Indexed.html), which will do what we're after.

```
fit = FindFit[dataA, Indexed[sol[ka, kd, beta], 1][t], {{ka, 0.7}, {kd, 0.1}, {beta, 0.1}}, t]
(*  {ka -> 0.932928, kd -> 0.136649, beta -> 0.0603392}  *)
```

In pre-V10, something like this will work (original answer):

```
firstIfList[l_List] := First[l]

fit = FindFit[dataA, firstIfList[sol[ka, kd, beta]][t], {{ka, 0.7}, {kd, 0.1}, {beta, 0.1}}, t]
(*  {ka -> 0.932928, kd -> 0.136649, beta -> 0.0603392}  *)
```

See [Prevent Part[] from trying to extract parts of symbolic expressions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14645/prevent-part-from-trying-to-extract-parts-of-symbolic-expressions) for a similar issue with `Part`.

Comment: `Indexed[sol[ka, kd, beta], 1][t]` also works.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks! I knew there was something new that solved this problem, but I forgot the name.

Comment: It's in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55175/121) in the Q&A you linked, if you'd like to vote for it. ;^)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Oops! I didn't read far enough. +1. :)

Comment: Thanks everybody for answering my questions! Good to know about Indexed!