# RecurrenceTable involving inputs from a vector

Tags: recursion, vector

Directly going to the issue, my problem is how to use a `RecurrenceTable` when it have inputs from a vector defined previously. For instance I have:

```
p={1,10,100,1000,10000};
```

And the recursive relation I want to solve is:

```
RecurrenceTable[{a[n + 1] == 2 a[n] + p[[n]], a[1] == 1}, a, {n, 1, 5}]
```

which must have an answer as:

> {1,3,16,132,1264}

But I face with this error:

```
Part::pkspec1: The expression n cannot be used as a part specification.
Part::pkspec1: The expression #1 cannot be used as a part specification.
```

For avoiding part specification I tried the following:

```
z = 1;
RecurrenceTable[{a[n + 1] == 2 a[n] + p[[z++]], a[1] == 1}, a, {n, 1, 5}]
```

But the answer is wrong:

> {1, 3, 7, 15, 31}

Comment: Related: [(14645)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14645/121)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [`Indexed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Indexed.html):

```
p = {1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000};

RecurrenceTable[{a[n + 1] == 2 a[n] + Indexed[p, n], a[1] == 1}, a, {n, 1, 5}]
```

> ```
> {1, 3, 16, 132, 1264}
> ```

Alternatives:

```
RecurrenceTable[{a[n + 1] == 2 a[n] + Unevaluated[p[[n]]], a[1] == 1}, a, {n, 1, 5}]
```

> ```
> {1, 3, 16, 132, 1264}
> ```

```
part[x_, n_Integer] := x[[n]]

RecurrenceTable[{a[n + 1] == 2 a[n] + part[p, n], a[1] == 1}, a, {n, 1, 5}]
```

> ```
> {1, 3, 16, 132, 1264}
> ```

Of course you could just [`Quiet`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quiet.html) the error and ignore it:

```
RecurrenceTable[{a[n + 1] == 2 a[n] + p[[n]], a[1] == 1}, a, {n, 1, 5}] // Quiet
```

> ```
> {1, 3, 16, 132, 1264}
> ```

Comment: Thanks a bunch @Mr.Wizard♦