# RecurrenceTable for systems of linear difference equations

Tags: numerics, difference-equations

I'm working on a project that involves developing a financial forecasting model. The equations used in the model will largely be linear difference equations (estimated via some form of regression analysis). Along with the difference equations will be additional equations that are simple identities, e.g., a[t] == b[t] + c[t], with no sort of time lag.

I've been experimenting with RecurrenceTable, using some simple hypothetical examples. For instance, this set of equations evaluates correctly:

```
 In[763]:= 
    model1 = RecurrenceTable[
      {
       x[t + 2] ==  
        0.25 + x[t + 1]  - 1.5*x[t] + 0.5*y[t + 1] + y[t + 2]  ,
       y[t + 2] == -0.50*y[t + 1] + 0.25*y[t] + x[t + 1] - 0.75*x[t + 2] ,
       z[t + 2] == 0.20*z[t + 1] + z[t] - 0.25*y[t + 2] - 1.5*x[t + 2] ,
       x[0] == 1, x[1] == 1,
       y[0] == 0, y[1] == 2,
       z[0] == 0, z[1] == 1},
      {x, y, z}, {t, 1, 10}
      ]

Out[763]= {{1., 2., 1.}, {0.428571, -0.321429, -0.3625}, {0.0612245, 
  1.04337, 0.574821}, {-0.200437, -0.390488, 0.150742}, {0.0103603, 
  0.247878, 0.52746}, {0.270717, -0.414239, -0.0462812}, {0.478779, 
  0.180722, -0.245145}, {0.398813, -0.0142515, -0.689967}, {0.214079, 
  0.29056, -0.776897}, {0.0436432, 0.0325037, -0.918937}}
```

If I modify this to include an additional equation, *q[t+2]* that simply sums the results of the other equations:

```
In[761]:= fcstB = RecurrenceTable[
  {
   x[t + 2] ==  
    0.25 + x[t + 1]  - 1.5*x[t] + 0.5*y[t + 1] + y[t + 2]  ,
   y[t + 2] == -0.50*y[t + 1] + 0.25*y[t] + x[t + 1] - 0.75*x[t + 2] ,
   z[t + 2] == 0.20*z[t + 1] + z[t] - 0.25*y[t + 2] - 1.5*x[t + 2] ,
   q[t + 2] == x[t + 2] + y[t + 2] + z[t + 2],
   x[0] == 1, x[1] == 1,
   y[0] == 0, y[1] == 2,
   z[0] == 0, z[1] == 1,
   q[0] == 1, q[1] == 4},
  {x, y, z, q}, {t, 1, 10}
  ]

Out[761]= RecurrenceTable[{x[2 + t] == 
   0.25 - 1.5 x[t] + x[1 + t] + 0.5 y[1 + t] + y[2 + t], 
  y[2 + t] == x[1 + t] - 0.75 x[2 + t] + 0.25 y[t] - 0.5 y[1 + t], 
  z[2 + t] == -1.5 x[2 + t] - 0.25 y[2 + t] + z[t] + 0.2 z[1 + t], 
  q[2 + t] == x[2 + t] + y[2 + t] + z[2 + t], x[0] == 1, x[1] == 1, 
  y[0] == 0, y[1] == 2, z[0] == 0, z[1] == 1, q[0] == 1, 
  q[1] == 4}, {x, y, z, q}, {t, 1, 10}]
```

The result does not evaluate. In looking through the documentation, it appears that RecurrenceTable will not handle trivial recurrence equations. I'm hoping someone can verify this for me, or perhaps suggest an alternative. The actual model I'm developing will consist of thousands of equations, and so it seems I will need to organize blocks of equations in such a way to isolate identities in order to evaluate the entire system

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to put it into a state-space form and then use [`OutputResponse`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OutputResponse.html).

I used [`AffineStateSpaceModel`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AffineStateSpaceModel.html) and not [`StateSpaceModel`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StateSpaceModel.html) because the equations have residue terms.

```
AffineStateSpaceModel[{x[t + 2] == 
    0.25 + x[t + 1] - 1.5*x[t] + 0.5*y[t + 1] + y[t + 2], 
   y[t + 2] == -0.50*y[t + 1] + 0.25*y[t] + x[t + 1] - 0.75*x[t + 2], 
   z[t + 2] == 
    0.20*z[t + 1] + z[t] - 0.25*y[t + 2] - 1.5*x[t + 2]}, {x[t], y[t],
    z[t]}, {u[t]}, {x[t], y[t], z[t]}, t];
OutputResponse[{%, {1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1}}, Table[0, 11]] // Transpose

(*{{1, 0, 0}, {1., 2., 1.}, {0.428571, -0.321429, -0.3625}, {0.0612245, 
  1.04337, 0.574821}, {-0.200437, -0.390488, 0.150742}, {0.0103603, 
  0.247878, 0.52746}, {0.270717, -0.414239, -0.0462812}, {0.478779, 
  0.180722, -0.245145}, {0.398813, -0.0142515, -0.689967}, {0.214079, 
  0.29056, -0.776897}, {0.0436432, 0.0325037, -0.918937}}*)
```

With the additional equation:

```
AffineStateSpaceModel[{x[t + 2] == 
    0.25 + x[t + 1] - 1.5*x[t] + 0.5*y[t + 1] + y[t + 2], 
   y[t + 2] == -0.50*y[t + 1] + 0.25*y[t] + x[t + 1] - 0.75*x[t + 2], 
   z[t + 2] == 0.20*z[t + 1] + z[t] - 0.25*y[t + 2] - 1.5*x[t + 2], 
   q[t + 2] == x[t + 2] + y[t + 2] + z[t + 2]}, {x[t], y[t], z[t], 
   q[t]}, {u[t]}, {x[t], y[t], z[t], q[t]}, t];
OutputResponse[{%, {1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 4}}, Table[0, 11], 
  Method -> "RecurrenceTable"] // Transpose

(*{{1, 0, 0, 1}, {1., 2., 1., 
  4.}, {0.428571, -0.321429, -0.3625, -0.255357}, {0.0612245, 1.04337,
   0.574821, 1.67941}, {-0.200437, -0.390488, 
  0.150742, -0.440183}, {0.0103603, 0.247878, 0.52746, 
  0.785699}, {0.270717, -0.414239, -0.0462812, -0.189803}, {0.478779, 
  0.180722, -0.245145, 
  0.414356}, {0.398813, -0.0142515, -0.689967, -0.305405}, {0.214079, 
  0.29056, -0.776897, -0.272258}, {0.0436432, 
  0.0325037, -0.918937, -0.84279}}*)
```

If you want you can explicitly ask [`OutputResponse`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OutputResponse.html) to use [`RecurrenceTable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RecurrenceTable.html) as I showed above. But it's not necessary.

Also applying [`Normal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normal.html) to the state-space model will give you equations in a form that can be solved by [`RecurrenceTable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RecurrenceTable.html).

Comment: Thank you for a very elegant solution!

Comment: Glad you liked it!

Answer (score 2):

`q` can be generated and combined with the corresponding values of `{x, y, z}`by

```
fcstB = Join[#, {Total@#}] & /@ model1
(* {{1., 2., 1., 4.}, 
    {0.428571, -0.321429, -0.3625, -0.255357}, 
    {0.0612245, 1.04337, 0.574821, 1.67941}, 
    {-0.200437, -0.390488, 0.150742, -0.440183}, 
    {0.0103603, 0.247878, 0.52746, 0.785699}, 
    {0.270717, -0.414239, -0.0462812, -0.189803}, 
    {0.478779, 0.180722, -0.245145, 0.414356}, 
    {0.398813, -0.0142515, -0.689967, -0.305405}, 
    {0.214079, 0.29056, -0.776897, -0.272258}, 
    {0.0436432, 0.0325037, -0.918937, -0.84279}} *)
```

Another approach is to solve these linear equations for `{x, y, z, q}` at `t + 2` and then apply `RecurrenceTable`:

```
rs = Solve[{x[t + 2] == 0.25 + x[t + 1] - 1.5*x[t] + 0.5*y[t + 1] + y[t + 2], 
            y[t + 2] == -0.50*y[t + 1] + 0.25*y[t] + x[t + 1] - 0.75*x[t + 2],
            z[t + 2] == 0.20*z[t + 1] + z[t] - 0.25*y[t + 2] - 1.5*x[t + 2], 
            q[t + 2] == x[t + 2] + y[t + 2] + z[t + 2]}, 
           {x[t + 2], y[t + 2], z[t + 2], q[t + 2]}] /. Rule -> Equal;
fcstB = RecurrenceTable[{rs, x[0] == 1, x[1] == 1, y[0] == 0, y[1] == 2, 
     z[0] == 0, z[1] == 1, q[0] == 1, q[1] == 4}, {x, y, z, q}, {t, 1, 10}]
```

which gives the same values as above.  It appears that `RecurrenceTable` was unhappy, because the original expression for `q[t +2]` did not depend explicitly on variables at earlier times.  But, who can say for sure without knowing the inner workings of the function.

**Addendum**

To test the hypothesis posed in the last paragraph above, let us add an infinitesimal amount of `q[t]` to the last equation in the original system.

```
fcstB = RecurrenceTable[{x[t + 2] == 0.25 + x[t + 1] - 1.5*x[t] + 0.5*y[t + 1] + y[t + 2], 
    y[t + 2] == -0.50*y[t + 1] + 0.25*y[t] + x[t + 1] - 0.75*x[t + 2], 
    z[t + 2] == 0.20*z[t + 1] + z[t] - 0.25*y[t + 2] - 1.5*x[t + 2], 
    q[t + 2] == x[t + 2] + y[t + 2] + z[t + 2] + 10^-30 q[t], 
    x[0] == 1, x[1] == 1, y[0] == 0, y[1] == 2, z[0] == 0, z[1] == 1, q[0] == 1, q[1] == 4}, 
    {x, y, z, q}, {t, 1, 10}]
```

which again evaluates to the desired answer.  I do not, of course, recommend this last approach for evaluating the `RecurrenceTable`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not find an other equation for q[t+2] with Eliminate.

```
eli = Eliminate[{x[t + 2] == 
0.25 + x[t + 1] - 1.5*x[t] + 0.5*y[t + 1] + y[t + 2], 
y[t + 2] == -0.50*y[t + 1] + 0.25*y[t] + x[t + 1] - 0.75*x[t + 2], 
z[t + 2] == 0.20*z[t + 1] + z[t] - 0.25*y[t + 2] - 1.5*x[t + 2], 
q[t + 2] == x[t + 2] + y[t + 2] + z[t + 2]}, 
{x[t + 2], y[t + 2], z[t + 2]}]

(*   0.166667\[VeryThinSpace]+ 1.09804 q[2 + t] + 0.509804 x[1 + t] - 
 0.0392157 y[t] + 0.411765 y[1 + t] - 1.09804 z[t] - 
 0.219608 z[1 + t] == x[t]   *)
```

Insert equation `eli` instead of q[t+2] == ...

```
fcstB = RecurrenceTable[{x[t + 2] == 
0.25 + x[t + 1] - 1.5*x[t] + 0.5*y[t + 1] + y[t + 2], 
y[t + 2] == -0.50*y[t + 1] + 0.25*y[t] + x[t + 1] - 0.75*x[t + 2], 
z[t + 2] == 0.20*z[t + 1] + z[t] - 0.25*y[t + 2] - 1.5*x[t + 2], 
eli, x[0] == 1, x[1] == 1, y[0] == 0, y[1] == 2, z[0] == 0, 
z[1] == 1, q[0] == 1, q[1] == 4}, {x, y, z, q}, {t, 0, 10}]

(*   {{1., 0., 0., 1.}, {1., 2., 1., 4.}, {0.428571, -0.321429, -0.3625, -0.255357}, {0.0612245, 1.04337,
0.574821, 1.67941}, {-0.200437, -0.390488, 
0.150742, -0.440183}, {0.0103603, 0.247878,  0.52746, 
0.785699}, {0.270717, -0.414239, -0.0462812, -0.189803}, {0.478779, 
0.180722, -0.245145, 
0.414356}, {0.398813, -0.0142515, -0.689967,  -0.305405}, {0.214079, 
0.29056, -0.776897, -0.272258}, {0.0436432, 
0.0325037, -0.918937, -0.84279}}   *)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/213954/recurrencetable-doesnt-evaluate-with-constant-right-hand-side).  The same workaround -- add `Unevaluated[0 q[t]]` -- works here:

```
fcstB = RecurrenceTable[{
   x[t + 2] == 0.25 + x[t + 1] - 1.5*x[t] + 0.5*y[t + 1] + y[t + 2], 
   y[t + 2] == -0.50*y[t + 1] + 0.25*y[t] + x[t + 1] - 0.75*x[t + 2], 
   z[t + 2] == 0.20*z[t + 1] + z[t] - 0.25*y[t + 2] - 1.5*x[t + 2], 
   q[t + 2] == x[t + 2] + y[t + 2] + z[t + 2] + Unevaluated[0 q[t]], 
   x[0] == 1, x[1] == 1, y[0] == 0, y[1] == 2, z[0] == 0, z[1] == 1, 
   q[0] == 1, q[1] == 4}, {x, y, z, q}, {t, 1, 10}]

(* {{1., 2., 1., 4.}, {0.428571, -0.321429, -0.3625, -0.255357},
{0.0612245, 1.04337, 0.574821, 1.67941}, {-0.200437, -0.390488, 0.150742, -0.440183},
{0.0103603, 0.247878, 0.52746, 0.785699}, {0.270717, -0.414239, -0.0462812, -0.189803},
{0.478779, 0.180722, -0.245145, 0.414356}, {0.398813, -0.0142515, -0.689967, -0.305405},
{0.214079, 0.29056, -0.776897, -0.272258}, {0.0436432, 0.0325037, -0.918937, -0.84279}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks. That is an interesting work-around. Any insight into why this approach works?

Comment: @MSC02476 I got the idea from [this answer by Mr. Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/197179/6358).  I suppose it tricks `RecurrenceTable` into thinking that `q[t+2]` is a function of `q[t]`.  The `Unevaluated` is needed because otherwise `0 q[t]` would be simplified to `0` first.