# Parametrize a circle as a tube?

Tags: plotting

I have this code:

```
Show[ContourPlot3D[{y == 0}, {x, -4, 6}, {y, -9, 1}, {z, -2, 8},
  Mesh -> {Range[-4, 6], Range[-9, 1], Range[-2, 8]},
  Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z},
  Ticks -> {Range[-4, 6, 1], Range[-9, 1, 1], Range[-2, 8, 1]}
  ],
 ParametricPlot3D[{3 Cos[φ] + 1, 0, 3 Sin[φ] + 3}, {φ, 
   0, 2 π},
  PlotStyle -> {Thickness[.02], Red}],
 Graphics3D[{Sphere[{1, -4, 3}, 5]}],
 ViewPoint -> {5, 5, 5}]
```

Which produces this image.

[image: my plot]

I have a couple of questions.

1. The intersection of the sphere with center at $(1,-4,3)$ and radius $5$ with the $xz$ plane is a circle with equation $(x-1)^2+(z-3)^2=9$. I parametrized the circle as 
   $x=3\cos\phi+1$, $y=0$, and $z=3\sin\phi+3$, then used `ParametricPlot3D` to add it to my picture. Anybody have a simple way of plotting the circle without my parametrization?
2. How can I add my circle so it looks like a tube?

Comment: [A related question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5968).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
cf[x_, y_, z_] := Plus @@ (({x, y, z} - {1, -4, 3})^2);
opts = {ViewPoint -> {5, 5, 5}, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
   Ticks -> {Range[-4, 6, 1], Range[-9, 1, 1], Range[-2, 8, 1]}, ImageSize -> 300};
```

**BoundaryStyle**

Use `BoundaryStyle->{{1,2}->Directive[Red, Tube@@#&]}` (or `BoundaryStyle -> {{1, 2} -> Directive[Red, # /. Line -> Tube &]}`)  to make the boundary between the sphere and the plane rendered as a red tube.

```
cp = ContourPlot3D[{cf[x, y, z]== 25,  y == 0}, {x, -4, 6}, {y, -9, 1}, {z, -2, 8}, 
  ContourStyle -> {Directive[Blue, Opacity[0.5]], Directive[Pink, Opacity[0.5]]}, 
  BoundaryStyle -> {1 -> None, 2 -> None, {1, 2} -> Directive[Red, Tube @@ # &]}, 
  Mesh -> None, Evaluate@opts]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
cp2 = ContourPlot3D[{y == 0}, {x, -4, 6}, {y, -9, 1}, {z, -2, 8}, 
  ContourStyle ->None, Mesh -> {Range[-4, 6], Range[-9, 1], Range[-2, 8]}];

Show[cp, cp2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**MeshFunctions**

```
cp3 = ContourPlot3D[cf[x, y, z] == 25, {x, -4, 6}, {y, -9, 1}, {z, -2, 8}, 
  ContourStyle -> Opacity[.5, Blue], 
  MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z}, y]}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
  MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, Tube @@ # &], Evaluate@opts]
```

or `MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, # /. Line -> Tube &]`, gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
cp4 = ContourPlot3D[{y == 0}, {x, -4, 6}, {y, -9, 1}, {z, -2, 8}, 
  ContourStyle -> Opacity[.5, Red], 
  Mesh -> {Range[-4, 6], Range[-9, 1], Range[-2, 8]}];

Show[cp3, cp4]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Notes:**  Two undocumented tricks are used in the above methods. 
The `BoundaryStyle` trick first appeared on this site in [this answer by Daniel Lichtblau](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5968) linked by @Guesswhoitis in the comments. It also features a second undocumented trick: using functions as style directives. On this second trick see [this page](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/809/) for relevant links.

**Post-processing**

Alternatively, you can post-process the `ContourPlot3D` output to change `Line` to `Tube`.

```
ContourPlot3D[{cf[x, y, z] == 25, y == 0}, {x, -4, 6}, {y, -9, 1}, {z, -2, 8}, 
  ContourStyle -> {Directive[Blue, Opacity[0.5]], Directive[Pink, Opacity[0.5]]}, 
  Mesh -> None, BoundaryStyle -> {1 -> None, 2 -> None, {1, 2} -> Red}, 
  Evaluate@opts] /. Line -> Tube

ContourPlot3D[cf[x, y, z] == 25, {x, -4, 6}, {y, -9, 1}, {z, -2, 8}, 
  ContourStyle -> Opacity[.5, Blue], MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z}, y]}, 
  Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> Red, Evaluate@opts] /. Line -> Tube
```

to get the same pictures as above.

**Update:**

> How would you use this code to make the tube larger?

This is easiest with the post-processing approach: simply change `/. Line->Tube` to `/. Line -> (Tube[#, .3]&)`.

With the first and second approaches, I expected that `Directive[Red, Tube[#, .3]& @@ # &]` would work, but it doesn't. However, `Directive[Red, Module[{tt = Tube[#, .3] &}, tt @@ # &]]` works.  It seems that, somehow, with another layer of function evaluation it gets too deep for `Directive` to process the primitive properly.

Alternatively, you can define a tube primitive function `tubeF` outside, and use it inside `Directive`:

```
ClearAll[tubeF]
tubeF[col_: Red, rad_: .1] := Module[{tf = Tube[#, rad] &}, Directive[col, tf @@ # &]];

Row[ContourPlot3D[{cf[x, y, z] == 25, y == 0}, {x, -4, 6}, {y, -9, 1}, {z, -2, 8}, 
    ContourStyle -> {Directive[Blue, Opacity[0.5]], Directive[Pink, Opacity[0.5]]},
    BoundaryStyle -> {1->None, 2->None, {1, 2}->#}, Mesh -> None, Evaluate@opts] & /@ 
 {tubeF[], tubeF[Orange, .3], tubeF[Purple, .5]}]
```

[image]

```
Row[ContourPlot3D[cf[x, y, z] == 25, {x, -4, 6}, {y, -9, 1}, {z, -2, 8},
    ContourStyle -> Opacity[.5, Blue], MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z}, y]}, 
    Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> #, Evaluate@opts] & /@
  {tubeF[], tubeF[Orange, .3], tubeF[Purple, .5]}]
```

[image]

Comment: First time I've seen something like: BoundaryStyle -> {1 -> None, 
  2 -> None, {1, 2} -> Directive[Red, Tube @@ # &]}. I'm assuming that 1 means the first contour, 2 means the second contour, and {1,2} means the intersection of the first and second contours. Where is this explained in the documentation? I went to BoundaryStyle, but did not find an example of this.

Comment: A second question regarding Tube @@ # &. Now, I looked up @@ for the fiftieth time and it replaces the head of expression by Tube. What is the head of the expression before it is replaced with Tube? Is there some sort of minimal example that would explain this?

Comment: @David. thank you the accept. As you discovered it is an undocumented trick. I updated with links to relevant answers that used the two undocumented methods. Re `Tube@@#&`, in this case, it replaces `Line` with `Tube`. See also the examples  [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/809/).

Comment: How would you use this code to make the tube larger? I have read an example in the documentation: Graphics3D[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}, .1]]. But if I use Directive[Red, Tube @@ # &], how do I add the size increase?

Comment: @David,   Defining `tube = Tube[#, .3] &` before `ContourPlot3D` is invoked and using `Directive[Red, tube @@ # &]` or `Directive[Red, # /. Line -> tube &]` works. (I thought `Directive[Red, Tube[#, .3]& @@ # &]` would work, but it doesn't.)

Comment: ... you can also use `Module` to define `tube` locally: `Module[{tube = Tube[#, .3] &},  ContourPlot3D[{cf[x, y, z] == 25, y == 0}, ...]`

Comment: Alternatively, you can use post-processing  to change `Tube` radius: `ContourPlot3D[....] /. Tube->(Tube[#,.3]&)`

Answer (score 4):

Just using a slightly different approach and using the derived circle and interpreting question as generating a torus from the circle of intersection between sphere and x-z plane:

```
s = ParametricPlot3D[
   5 {Sin[u] Cos[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[u]} + {1, -4, 3}, {u, 0, 
    Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, y <= 0], Mesh -> None];
t[r_, p_, b_] := 
  ParametricPlot3D[
   p + b {Cos[u], 0, Sin[u]} + 
    r Cos[v] {Cos[u], 0, Sin[u]} + {0, r Sin[v], 0}, {u, 0, 
    2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> False, PlotStyle -> Red];
Manipulate[
 Show[s, t[r, {1, 0, 3}, 3], Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
  Background -> Black, PlotRange -> All], {r, Range[0.05, 0.5, 0.05]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Nice animation. I used a piece of your code to ask another question. See: [http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84163/mathematicas-viewpoint-versus-matlabs-view-command](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84163/mathematicas-viewpoint-versus-matlabs-view-command).