# Mathematica's ViewPoint versus MATLAB's View command

Tags: plotting

Here is a bit of code borrowed from [Parametrize a circle as a tube?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84146).

```
ParametricPlot3D[
 5 {Sin[u] Cos[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[u]} + {1, -4, 3}, {u, 0, 
  Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi},
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, y <= 0],
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

When you rotate an image in MATLAB, the azimuth and elevation appears in the lower left-hand corner, which you can then use in the view command in your code.

Does *Mathematica* have a similar tool? I really like to rotate the image until I get a view that I really like. Then I'd like some view some information that I can use in my code.

**Suggestion by Guess who it is: **

[image]

Comment: Apply `Options[]` to your 3D plot after spinning it around.

Comment: BTW: when tagging, please use the most relevant tag. If your question is more about, say, how to plot a derivative rather than the actual derivative, then the appropriate tag is [tag:plotting], not [tag:calculus-and-analysis].

Comment: @Guess who it is How do you apply Options[] to the 3D plot after spinning it around? I tried Options[%]. Not sure what you mean to do.

Comment: Something like `Options[(* insert the actual 3D plot here *)]`; spin the plot inside the `Options[]` around, and whenever you see something you like, Shift-Enter to see the viewing parameters, among other things.

Comment: Thanks. It worked! See my edit in my original post. Although, it might only be appropriate for the smaller image.

Comment: No, those settings are not size-dependent; try it out for yourself.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps this will be helpful in exploring. At the end of gif I am trying to illustrate you can select, copy and paste the desired option values.

```
pl = ParametricPlot3D[
   5 {Sin[u] Cos[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[u]} + {1, -4, 3}, {u, 0, 
    Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, y <= 0]];
DynamicModule[{vp, va, vv, 
  vc}, {vp, va, vv, 
   vc} = {ViewPoint, ViewAngle, ViewVertical, ViewCenter} /. 
   AbsoluteOptions[pl];
 Panel[Column[{
    Show[pl, SphericalRegion -> True, ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp], 
     ViewAngle -> Dynamic[va], ViewVertical -> Dynamic[vv], 
     ViewCenter -> Dynamic[vc]],
    Dynamic[
     Grid@Transpose[{{ViewPoint, ViewAngle, ViewVertical, 
         ViewCenter}, {vp, va, vv, vc}}]],
    Row[{"vcx", Slider[Dynamic[vc[[1]]], {0, 1}]}],
    Row[{"vcy", Slider[Dynamic[vc[[2]]], {0, 1}]}],
    Row[{"vcz", Slider[Dynamic[vc[[3]]], {0, 1}]}]
    }]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I use this idiom for this:

```
Defer[AbsoluteOptions][
 Graphics3D[Cuboid[]]]
```

Which just pre-heads the output so you don't have to type around the graphics object. I find that `ViewPoint` and `ViewVertical` are the two settings I need to recover the orientations I play around with:

```
Defer[{ViewPoint, ViewVertical} /. AbsoluteOptions[#] &][
 Graphics3D[Cuboid[]]]
```

To make this into a function:

```
viewSpec[g_] := Module[{f},
   f = Thread[{ViewPoint, ViewVertical} -> ({ViewPoint, ViewVertical} /. AbsoluteOptions[#])] &;
   Defer[f][g]];

viewSpec[Graphics3D[Cuboid[]]]
```

Here's one way to make a more native-like appearance (click on the button to copy to clipboard):

```
viewHUD[Graphics3D[all___]] := 
  Module[{vv = {0, 0, 1}, vp = {1.3, -2.4, 2}}, (*defaults from documentation*)
   Print[Dynamic[
     Module[{spec = {ViewVertical -> vv, ViewPoint -> vp}},
      Button[spec, CopyToClipboard[spec]; Beep[]]]]];

   Graphics3D[all, ViewVertical -> Dynamic[vv], ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp]]];

viewHUD[Graphics3D[Cuboid[]]]
```

You can also stringify the specification and trim the surrounding curly braces before you `CopyToClipboard` so that you can paste them easier.

And by the way, there isn't really any way you would have known to go about these things in these ways. Some of these deeper things (like knowing you can Dynamize and therefore link the view settings in Graphics3D) is just from playing around and investigating them.

Comment: Probably, you intended to write `ViewPoint -> vp` instead of `ViewVector -> vp`…

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. you're right ty. fixed. i am dyslexic with respect to mathematica 3D view specification parameter names.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
     Manipulate[
        ParametricPlot3D[
         5 {Sin[u] Cos[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[u]} + {1, -4, 3}, 
      {u, 0, Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, 
        RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, y <= 0], 
        AxesLabel -> {x, y, z},
        ViewPoint -> 
   5 {Cos[θ] Sin[ϕ], Sin[θ] Sin[ϕ], Cos[ϕ]}],
     {θ, 0, 2 π, Appearance -> "Open"},
     {ϕ, 0, π, Appearance -> "Open"}]
```