# Correct definition of a function to be passed to Nintegrate

Tags: numerical-integration, assignment

If I type the following code

```
τMin0 = 0.1; 
τMax0 = 2; 
integrand[(τ_)?NumericQ] := {1000/Sqrt[τ^2 - τMin0^2], 0}; 
2*NIntegrate[Evaluate[integrand[τ][[1]]], {τ, τMin0, τMax0}]
2*NIntegrate[1000/Sqrt[τ^2 - τMin0^2], {τ, τMin0, τMax0}]
```

I obtain two different values for the same integrals

```
3.99
7376.51
```

The first integral is of course not well calculated  (I have checked by comparing with the analytical solutions in `arccos`). I don't know why and what to do to fix it.

Comment: The expression `Evaluate[integrand[τ][[1]]]` actually evaluates to `τ`. You need to `Hold` the expression inside `NIntegrate` to prevent premature application of `Part`: `NIntegrate[Hold[integrand[τ] [[1]] ], {τ, τMin0, τMax0}]`. See [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14603/27951) and [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8643/27951).

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear[integrand]
```

With your definition that uses an unnecessary list and then takes a part

```
integrand[t_?NumericQ] := {1000/Sqrt[t^2 - tMin0^2], 0};

integrand[t][[1]]
```

> t

This occurs because `integrand` cannot evaluate with a symbolic input so the first part of the unevaluated expression is the function's argument.

```
Clear[integrand]

tMin0 = 1/10;
tMax0 = 2;
integrand[t_?NumericQ] := 1000/Sqrt[t^2 - tMin0^2];
2*NIntegrate[integrand[t], {t, tMin0, tMax0}]
2*NIntegrate[1000/Sqrt[t^2 - tMin0^2], {t, tMin0, tMax0}]
```

> 7376.51
>
> 7376.51

Comparing with the exact value

```
2*Integrate[1000/Sqrt[t^2 - tMin0^2], {t, tMin0, tMax0}]
```

> 2000 Log[20 + Sqrt[399]]

```
% // N
```

> 7376.51

Comment: Of course the list is needed in what I want to do. This piece of  code is a part of a much bigger one where the list is needed. I have just simplified it for the sake of clarity and to provide the minimum example.