# How to change plot style or other options after it was created

Tags: plotting, options, expression-manipulation

For example:

```
p = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

Is it possible to write options in `Show` to change the curve's color for example into red?

```
Show[p, (* Option?? *)]
```

Comment: `p = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}];
col = Cases[p, _Hue, Infinity][[1]];
Show[p /. col -> Red]`   - not sure if this really merits an answer?

Comment: just to make sure, you wanted the `Show` way (to work on already existing plots), not simply a `Plot[...,PlotStyle->Red]` kind of solution ?

Answer (score 46):

I already answered this question on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5645482/618728) but since old questions can no longer be migrated without undue trouble I shall reproduce my answer here.

---

There are two different categories of graphical objects in a `Plot` output.

1. The plotted lines of the functions (`Sin[x]`, `Cos[x]`) and their styles are "hard coded" into `Line` objects, which `Graphics` can understand.
2. Auxiliary settings such as `Axes -> True`, `PlotLabel -> "Sine Cosecant Plot"` and `AxesStyle -> Orange` are understood by `Graphics` directly, without conversion, and therefore remain within the `myplot` object.

The second kind of settings can be easily changed after the fact because they are soft settings. (e.g. `Show[p, (* options *)]`

The first kind much be processed in some way.  This is complicated by the fact that different `*Plot` functions output different patterns of `Graphics` and `Plot` itself may give different patterns of output depending on the input it is given.

I am not aware of any global way to restyle all plot types, and if you do such restyling often, it probably makes more sense to retain the data that is required and simply regenerate the graphic with Plot.  Nevertheless, for basic uses, your method can be improved.  Each function plotted creates a `Line` object, in the given order.  Therefore, you can use something like this to completely restyle a plot:

```
myplot = Plot[{Cos[x], Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Red, Dashing[None]}, {Green, Dashing[None]}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
newstyles = Directive @@@ {
    {Green, Thickness[.02], Dashing[Tiny]},
    {Thickness[Large], Red}
  };

i = 1;
MapAt[# /. {__, ln__Line} :> {newstyles[[i++]], ln} &, myplot, {1, 1}]
```

[image]

Please note the part `{1, 1}` in the last line of code above.  This is the part specification for the location of the `Line` objects within `myplot`.  It is specified so as not to accidentally style Lines that might appear in other parts of the `Graphics` object.  This part may need to be changed; for example when using `Filling` the Lines end up in `{1, 2}`.  For this reason in the function below I simply used `1` which will be more flexible but could conceivably conflict with something.

#### Restyle function

The method above can be made into a self-contained function.
I will use [this method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3876/121) to cycle the styles given.

```
restylePlot[plot_Graphics, styles_List, op : OptionsPattern[Graphics]] :=
 Module[{x = styles}, Show[
   MapAt[# /. {__, ln__Line} :> {Directive @ Last[x = RotateLeft@x], ln} &, plot, 1],
   op
 ]]
```

Example:

```
myplot2 = Plot[Evaluate[Table[BesselJ[n, x], {n, 4}]], {x, 0, 10}, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
restylePlot[myplot2,
 {
  {Green, Thickness[.02], Dashing[Tiny]},
  {Thickness[Large], Red},
  Blue
 },
 Axes -> False,
 Frame -> True,
 FrameStyle -> Directive[20, FontColor -> Orange]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You will notice that the filling styles have not changed.  While it is possible to change these by using `GraphicsGroup` in place of `Line` in the replacement rule the structure is considerably more complex to the point of being inconvenient.  (It would probably be better to use the Graphics Inspector, or preferably to regenerate the graphic.)

---

#### Graphics Inspector

While I personally tend to avoid extensive after-Plot restyling because I like to keep everything in one place (the `Plot` command), and I prefer to make what changes I do with code so that there is a record of my settings without having to dig into the `Graphics` object, the Graphics Inspector is directly applicable.

- Double click the plot.  The border should change from orange to thick gray.
- Single click one of the plot lines. (the pointed should change when you hover over an element)
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> to open the Graphics Inspector.
- Make the changes you desire, and close the Graphics Inspector.

You can now copy and paste the entire graphic, or directly assign it to a symbol: `p = <graphic>`

Also see:  https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/EditWolframLanguageGraphics.html

---

Tangentially related:

[How to change the default ColorData used in Mathematica's Plot?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4712/121)

[Filling Styles using a single Plot in Mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8566706/618728)

Comment: btw, I like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8569242) too... You should find a place for this here.

Comment: Yes, it works, but  you need to fix a typo in the definition – `MapAt[..., plot, 1]`. Also, my dashings look [very different](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nwfzv.png) (like thick solid green). Do you have custom settings?

Comment: @Hypnotoad thanks! hm... I don't think I've got custom dashing.  I better look at that.

Comment: @Hypnotoad how does `Thickness[.02], Dashing[Tiny]` look in other plots?

Comment: It looks same as in the above plot. I'm not surprised though, because I always run into trouble with `Thickness` (since it's based on the plot size and possibly other things). I always use `AbsoluteThickness` for these.

Comment: Exceptional response. Bookmarking this!!

Comment: @Jérémie Thanks, I'm glad it helps.  Please let me know if you have any problems, or if it doesn't display as expected (see rm's comment above).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I love the green plot with high thickness and small dashing, but when I attempt to increase thickness it seems to increase the thickness of each 'dash' in every direction, thus obscuring the dashing pattern. A possible newer-mma-version bug? I'm using 11.0.0.0.

Comment: @Max You're right.  This works as (I think) it should in v.10.1 but in v11.1 on Open Cloud I get a solid line.  Would you please post a question about this?  for reference here is the exact code I used: `Plot[{Cos[x], Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, {Green, Thickness[.02], Dashing[Tiny]}}]`.  Also using `Directive` does not change behavior on either version, i.e. `Plot[{Cos[x], Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Directive[Green, Thickness[.02], Dashing[Tiny]]}]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks for checking, I submitted the question with your code (though I had to modify it to fit the narrative) here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/143873/thickness-destroys-dashing-in-v11-0-0-0-or-earlier

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Now it's looking like an OS issue? See Edit on my question.

Answer (score 33):

Ah well... this is *not* robust, but probably of educational value and useful as a starting point for other post-processing needs on `Graphics` or `Graphics3D` expressions:

```
p = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}]
col = Cases[p, _Hue, Infinity][[1]];
Show[p /. col -> Red]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Update: As pointed out by matheorem,  Version 10 switched from `Hue` to `RGBColor`,  so the `Cases`statement has to be changed accordingly,  preferably (thanks to @rcollyer) using `ColorQ` to cover all future bases. (e.g. `Show[p /. _?ColorQ -> Red]`)

Comment: Neat example, but worth

Comment: Thank you very much! You're so clever! But I found an easier way inspired by your idea. A single line **Show[p/._Hue->Red]** will be enough!

Comment: @user15964 thanks for the unexpected praise =). It is very good to see you managed an even simpler solution (mine may still be of use for plots with multiple colors).

Comment: @YvesKlett Oh, I just found that in Mathematica 10, Hue is not working any more. They have changed Hue into RBGColor. So now in M10, we have to use `p/._RGBColor->Red`. Since your answer is most popular, you may add a note to it.

Comment: @matheorem thanks for the heads-up! Glad I put the robustness disclaimer in there. Will amend asap.

Comment: @YvesKlett use `_?ColorQ` instead for v10 as it covers all your bases.

Comment: For fun: `Animate[Plot[Evaluate[Table[1/(x - 2 n), {n, 4}]], {x, 0, 10}, Filling -> Axis] /. c_?ColorQ :> Function[{h, s, b}, Hue[h + a, s, b]] @@ ColorConvert[c, "HSB"], {a, 0, 1}]`

Comment: @rcollyer Wow, you are so familiar with new features of M10.

Comment: @matheorem it helps that I'm testing the functionality before it is released to the public.

Comment: `_?ColorQ` results in several `Part::partw` warnings: `Part 2 of #1 does not exist`. It may be better to use `_Hue|_RGBColor` to check for expected `Head` without evaluation.

Comment: @rcollyer: any way of using the `_?ColorQ` to change two or more lines to different colors? Or do I need to use Mr.Wizard's [restyle function](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17270)?

Comment: @riddleculous `_?ColorQ` is just a pattern, you use it to find things. So, yes the `restyle` function would be the way to go.

Comment: @rcollyer thanks, I expected so, but I had the hope one might be able to somehow find a pattern only once, use the replacement rule and then find the next pattern (which is the same) and replace this. But I have no idea how this should even look like since the second (same) pattern would match the same (first) occurrence again

Answer (score 16):

As Mr.Wizard indicated, you can also reconstruct the plot using the data. Here is an example:

```
restylePlot2[p_, op : OptionsPattern[ListLinePlot]] := 
    ListLinePlot[Cases[Normal@p, Line[x__] :> x, ∞], op, Options[p]]
```

then we can set the style as we do in plot. For example

```
restylePlot2[myplot2, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Green, Thick, Dashed}, {Thickness[Large], Red}, Blue},
  Filling -> Axis, FrameStyle -> Directive[20, FontColor -> Orange], 
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{"1", "2", "3", "4"}]]
```

[image]

I found it useful when sometime I want to combine several plots:

```
pls = Table[Plot[Sin[n x], {x, 0, 2 π}], {n, 1, 3}];
```

[image]

```
restylePlot2[pls, Joined -> True, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, PlotLegends -> {"1", "2", "3"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice idea.  I think you are missing `Joined -> True` in the first example; I recommend using `ListLinePlot` rather than `Joined -> True` anyway.  Also this loses any options from the original including any `Prolog` and `Epilog` that may exist.  I think it would be better to filter the old options and use them as the defaults, allowing them to be overridden by any new ones that are given.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks for pointing out, I was setting `Joined->True` to be the default setting in my Mathematica so I didn't notice. But for the old options, I did attach them to the end so I think `Epilog`, `Prolog` etc. should be alright.

Comment: I somehow either missed or misread that.  One refinement you might make: use `OptionsPattern[ListLinePlot]` as that is the function that will be receiving the options.