# How can I combine two plots that were created in different notebooks?

Tags: plotting

I have two different programs for simulating a system.
when I get the results I have plotting result for each.
now I want to combine both drawings so that I compare between them.
I want to put both of them on the same picture.
How I can do that?
for example; I will attach two drawings.
[image]
[image]

my second question is that how to change the color of the line after drawing?

Comment: Did you have a look at `Show`?

Comment: Like @Anon said Show should do the trick if I understand your question. Please elaborate on your problem.

Comment: @abhilashsukumari Yes I know `Show` command. but this command is for the case when you have both result in the same program. but in my case I have two different programs, so I can't say `Show[Plot1, Plot2]`

Comment: @barznjy, what do you mean by having two different programs? Did you use mathematica to create the plots, or another program? You don't have all of the data accessible in a single notebook?  Do you still have the data, or just the plots?

Comment: @JasonB I am doing simulation of different systems, for each system there is its own equations and calculations. I use Mathematica for both calculation and plotting. I usually do several steps of calculations then plotting the results. So, I have different notebooks. It is not possible that I put all programs in the same notebook. Even if I put programs in the same notebook I can't run them simulatanously.

Comment: In MatLab it is very easy, you can copy and paste the plotting. and it will copy the legend too. But I don't know how to do that in Mathematica.

Comment: @barznjy, What is the result when you try to do exactly that in Mathematica?  Open the two notebooks that have the plots in them (call them notebooks 1 and 2), then open a new notebook (notebook 3).  Highlight the plot from notebook 1 and hit copy.  Go into notebook 3, type `g1=` then hit paste, and enter.  Do the same with notebook 2, naming that graphic `g2`.  Finally, just enter `Show[g1,g2]`.  You should get what you want.

Comment: @barznjy I do agree that you have to better state your question, but I just assumed this was a non-native English problem.  Here, the most descriptive title for your question would be "How can I combine two plots that were created in different notebooks".  That can help us to figure out how to help you.  Also, I just noticed that there was a second question, concerning how to change the colors of the plots after you've created them.  The answer can be found here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17250/is-it-possible-to-change-the-color-of-plot-in-show

Answer (score 3):

```
(*let's simmulate your environment*)

(*First we create a notebook*)
nb1 = CreateDocument[ExpressionCell[Defer[p1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]], "Input"]];
(* The another one *)
nb2 = CreateDocument[ExpressionCell[Defer[p2 = Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]], "Input"]];
(*pause*)
DialogInput[ DialogNotebook[{TextCell[
               "We have created two NBs (Check the open windows) \n Press OK to calculate both NBs"], 
             Button["OK", DialogReturn[]]}]];
NotebookEvaluate[nb1, InsertResults -> True];
NotebookEvaluate[nb2, InsertResults -> True];
DialogInput[
 DialogNotebook[{TextCell[
   "Now we have evaluated both Notebooks \n Press OK to close the Nbs and show both plots together"], 
                Button["OK", DialogReturn[]]}]]
NotebookClose /@ {nb1, nb2};
Show[p1, p2]
```