# Edit Plot/Graphics after it's been drawn.

Tags: plotting, graphics

Sometimes I run into a situation when there are graphics objects (mostly plots) that take a while to draw. Good practice would suggest you do all your evaluation outside `Plot` or whatever other plotting function, but sometimes one forgets or it is the drawing process that takes so much time. So **the question is**  whether it is possible to change things such as `PlotLabel` font, `PlotStyle` or other strictly aesthetic properties of the plot without asking Mathematica to recalculate all the points.

Comment: You can still ask for the `FullForm`/`InputForm` and change the `Options`

Comment: Oh wow, this works very well, I haven't worked much with `FullForm` so I didn't think of it.

Comment: I feel that this question is a duplicate and that it would be better to gather all answers under the following question: [(17250)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17250/121)

Answer (score 9):

It depends. Some options, like e.g. `PlotStyle` are directly incorporated into the graphics itself. Others, like `PlotLabel`, are still there as options in the graphics and can be changed.

```
gr = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}];
Show[gr, PlotLabel -> "Boing"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Please have a look at `AbsoluteOptions[gr]` to see which options are still available. I'm not entirely sure whether the above approach with `Show` works always but there are of course many alternatives. One of them is to build a new `Graphics` object. For this you take the first part, which consists of all the graphics primitives and you use the `AbsoluteOptions`. To replace the `GridLines` for instance, you could use

```
Graphics[First[gr], 
 Sequence @@ (AbsoluteOptions[gr] /. 
 (GridLines -> _) :> (GridLines -> {{{Pi, Dashed}, {2 Pi, Thick}}, 
  {{-1, Orange}, -.5, .5, {1, Orange}}}))]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Be aware that usually you don't need to *replace* the options. If you put the same option twice, it's always first comes first serves. Therefore, this works too

```
Graphics[First[gr], 
 GridLines -> {{{Pi, Dashed}, {2 Pi, Thick}}, {{-1, 
     Orange}, -.5, .5, {1, Orange}}}, Sequence @@ AbsoluteOptions[gr]]
```

Additionally, you should be aware that you can work with a `Graphics` object like with any other expression in *Mathematica*. Therefore, even if it is not as simple as setting an option, you can still change every detail of the graphics. this needs quite some knowledge about the structure of `Graphics` itself, but it is not impossible. Just like Öska said, look at the `InputForm`

```
gr /. _Hue :> Red
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: So just to be clear - options shown under `AbsoluteOptions` are editable? There are some things you can change in the style of the plot by what @Öskå proposed (I managed to change the color of a particular line segment and such) but it is very bothersome and I can't think of the top of my head when redrawing wouldn't e be simpler.

<b>Edited:</b> you updated your answer with the things I commented here.

Comment: @JānisŠmits I'm not sure whether every option can be set with this simple `Show[..]` construct I used, but you can always build a new graphics with something like `Graphics[First[gr], Sequence@@AbsoluteOptions[gr]]` and here, you you simply replace an option by something you like. Should I give full example in the answer?

Comment: If it isn't too much of a hassle, this is the first time I have heard of the Sequence function, I looked it up, but I think it would be very nice to have an example of how to do this in this situation.

Comment: I feel that this question is a duplicate and that it would be better to gather all answers under the following question: [(17250)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17250/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard How do we do that except of closing this question here? The problem is that the title "Is it possible to change the color of plot in Show?" does not reflect what has been asked here (at least not, if you don't know the answer anyway). That might be one reason why the OP hasn't found the other thread.

Comment: As you can see I did not close this question as work would be needed.  Should you agree you could edit the original question to reflect both aspects, then have me merge the questions to move your answer there.  If you disagree that's fine too.