# How to make an arbitrary number of plots have different labels/colors/etc?

Tags: plotting, legending

I'm sorry but I'm not sure how to phrase this question well. Frequently I have a function that produces and returns a Plot[] or array of Plot[]'s, which I can then display with Show[], or combine with Plot[]'s from another function and then use Show[].

Normally to tell which curve is which on a graph with many curves, you have a legend. Except here, the function produced an arbitrary number of plots, and also I maybe later want to combine them with other Plot[]'s in Show[], so they all have the same color in the legend.

Is there a way to make Show[] give them different colors so I can tell them apart? I can think of some very contrived ways to do this (make some sort of global variable that keeps track of how many plots have been created, and uses this as a counter to change the color to be used for the next plot), but they're very ugly and I imagine there must be a better way in elegant MM.

Does anyone know of one?

Thank you!

Edit: An example of the code:

```
(*Creates and returns a plot.*)
PlotSomething[freq0_] := (
Plot[Sin[freq0*x], {x,0,3.14}])

(*Call the above plotting function several times, create and return an array of Plots.*)
MakePlotArray[numplots_] := (
plottable = {};For[i = 1, i <= numplots, i++,
AppendTo[plottable, PlotSomething[i]];
];
Return[plottable];)

(*How can I make these plots have different colors and labels?*)
Show[MakePlotArray[5]]
```

Comment: Please include code to produce "an arbitrary number of plots" in the same manner that you have in your application.

Comment: @rm-rf Of course, sorry. Let me do that. What I mean by 'arbitrary' is different every time I call the function, depending on the arguments.

Comment: It could be much better if you provide a boilerplate that doesn't need external resources (files, functions). Just a small simulation of random data able to run stand-alone.

Comment: @belisarius Sorry, I didn't think about making it directly runnable, just to show what I meant. I've modified it to make it standalone and produce what I mean.

Comment: @YungHummmma Much better now. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if there's an elegant way.  The colors are embedded in the plots, and changing them after the fact takes some work.  I basically do what the OP alluded to, but as postprocessing.  Collect the colors in the graph and remap them according to some color function.

```
plots = Table[
  Plot[Evaluate[Table[Sin[(4(3-j)-i)x], {i, 4-j}]], {x, 0, 2 Pi}],
  {j, 3}];

remapColors[plots_, colorFunction_ : (Hue[#, 0.6, 0.6] &)] := 
 Module[{n=0, colors, ncolors},
  colors=DeleteDuplicates @ Cases[First@#, _RGBColor | _Hue, Infinity] &/@ plots;
  ncolors=Length @ Flatten @ colors;
  MapThread[#1 /. (#1 -> colorFunction[Rescale[++n, {1, ncolors}]] &/@ #2) &,
   {plots, colors}]
 ]

Show[
 remapColors[plots, ColorData["Rainbow"]]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Caveat:  If the plots contain styles that have colors, such as a styled `Tootlip`, those colors will be remapped, too.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's the best way to do it. Just to be clear, I also don't really care about the colors exactly -- I just want to be able to tell which curve is which in a legend off to the side, when I combine all these Plots. I also don't really care about doing it this way -- I guess a better way would be to return the arrays before plotting them, and then pass them to a function to plot them all at once (thus letting me make them different colors and label them easily)?

Comment: @YungHummmma I think plotting them all at once is the easiest way (perhaps the only way) to get the legends to automatically match the curves.

Answer (score 4):

I am also going to propose a post-processing approach, but I will base my answer on my existing `restylePlot` function from [Is it possible to change the color of plot in Show?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17250/is-it-possible-to-change-the-color-of-plot-in-show/17270#17270)
That function again for reference:

```
restylePlot[plot_Graphics, styles_List, op : OptionsPattern[Graphics]] :=
 Module[{x = styles}, Show[
   MapAt[# /. {__, ln__Line} :> {Directive @ Last[x = RotateLeft@x], ln} &, plot, 1],
   op
 ]]
```

Five plots all generated with the default style:

```
 plots = Table[Plot[BesselJ[n, x], {x, 0, 10}], {n, 5}];
```

[image]

Basic application of `restylePlot`:

```
combined = 
  restylePlot[
    Show[plots],
    ColorData[3, "ColorList"],
    BaseStyle -> Thick
  ]
```

[image]

Note:

- `BaseStyle` in can be used to affect all lines at once
- The color list given as the second argument will be used cyclically

To add a legend you may use Jens' `legendMaker` code from [Creating legends for plots with multiple lines?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4025/creating-legends-for-plots-with-multiple-lines/4028#4028) as follows:

```
legend =
  legendMaker[
    Array[TraditionalForm @ BesselJ[#, x] &, 5], 
    PlotStyle -> ColorData[3, "ColorList"]
  ]
```

[image]

```
Show[
 combined,
 Prolog -> Inset[Style[legend, 18], {1, -0.18}],
 ImageSize -> 600
]
```

[image]

These steps can of course be automated but I leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 3):

Small mod to the above to draw a legend..

```
 remapColors[plots_, colorFunction_ : (Hue[#, 0.6, 0.6] &)] := 
     Module[{n = 0, colors, ncolors},
       colors = 
        DeleteDuplicates@Cases[First@#, _RGBColor | _Hue, Infinity] & /@ 
          plots;
     ncolors = Length@Flatten@colors;
     newcolors = Table[ colorFunction@(i/ncolors) , {i, ncolors }];
     MapThread[#1 /. (#1 -> newcolors[[++n]] & /@ #2) &, {plots, colors}]]

 legend[col_] := 
     Graphics[Table[{{col[[i]], z = .1 + .1 i; Line[{{7, z}, {8, z}}]}, 
        Text[Style[ToString[i]], {8.6, z}]}, {i, Length[col]}]]
 Show[{remapColors[plots, ColorData["Rainbow"]], legend@newcolors}, 
         PlotRange -> {{0, 9}, Automatic}]
```

[image]

Really preferable to assemble the data into a single plot if feasible of course.

Caveat: If your base plots have colors specified via `PlotStyle` they end up with extra unused colors which then end up in the legend.. I don't see a straightforward way around that.