# Want a different color for each curve displayed with Show

Tags: plotting, color, legending

I want a different color for each curve that I am displaying with Show.

The functions are: `custom1 custom2 custom3 custom4 custom5`, and I am using the following code to plot these functions;

```
Show[
  Histogram[R, Automatic, "PDF"], 
  Plot[Evaluate[Tooltip[PDF[#, x], #]], {x, 0, 1}] & /@ 
    {custom1[26.99,0.17, 13, 3.58, 0.77, 45.11], 
     custom2[152.84, 4.89, 4.91, 0.28, 172.13], 
     custom3[37.75, 0.35, 1.09, 29.49], 
     custom4[20880.9, 0.29, 21634.8],
     custom5[3.08, 5.39]}]
```

The graph is:

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43815/3066)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
r = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 1500];
custom = NormalDistribution[#, 1] & /@ Range[0, 2, .4]; 
(* to be replaced with your custom1, custom2, ... *)
```

You can do one of several things:

**Make a single `Plot` instead of five separate ones**

```
Show[Histogram[r, Automatic, "PDF"], 
     Plot[Evaluate[Tooltip[PDF[#, x], #] & /@ custom], {x, -3, 3}]]
(* or Plot[Tooltip[PDF[#, x], #] & /@ custom, {x, -3, 3}, Evaluated -> True] *)
```

[image]

**Or provide individual colors in each of `Plot`s:**

```
Show[Histogram[r, Automatic, "PDF"], 
 Plot[Evaluate[Tooltip[PDF[#, x], #]], {x, -3, 3}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Thick, Hue[RandomReal[]]}] & /@ custom]
```

[image]

```
Block[{i = 1}, Show[Histogram[r, Automatic, "PDF"], With[{j = i++},
     Plot[Evaluate[Tooltip[PDF[#, x], #]], {x, -3, 3},
      PlotStyle -> {Thick, ColorData[63, "ColorList"][[j]]}]] & /@ custom]]
```

[image]

**Update:** add legends

```
Legended[Block[{i = 1}, 
  Show[Histogram[r, Automatic, "PDF"], 
   With[{j = i++}, Plot[Evaluate[Tooltip[PDF[#, x], #]], {x, -3, 3}, 
       PlotStyle -> {Thick, ColorData[63, "ColorList"][[j]]}]] & /@ custom]], 
 LineLegend[ColorData[63, "ColorList"][[;; 5]], 
            {"custom1", "custom2", "custom3", "custom4", "custom5"}]]
```

[image]

**Update 2:** You can also put everything in a single `Plot` using the `PDF` of  `HistogramDistribution`:

```
hd = HistogramDistribution[r];
custom2 = Prepend[custom, hd];
legendlabels = (Style[#, "Panel", 14] & /@ custom2 /. 
              DataDistribution[___] :> "HistogramDistribution[r]");

Plot[Tooltip[PDF[#, x], #] & /@ custom2, {x, -3, 3},
 LabelStyle -> {16, "Panel", Background -> None}, BaseStyle -> Thick,
 PlotStyle -> ColorData[63, "ColorList"], Evaluated -> True, Exclusions -> False, 
 FillingStyle -> (Lighter@Lighter@ColorData[63, "ColorList"][[1]]), 
 Filling -> {1 -> Axis}, PlotLegends -> legendlabels]
```

[image]

**Another update:** Two additional methods with minimal changes in OP's code to add random colors:

**Post-process the `Line`s to add color directives:**

```
op = Show[Histogram[r, Automatic, "PDF"], 
   Plot[Evaluate[Tooltip[PDF[#, x], #]], {x, -3, 3}] & /@ custom, ImageSize -> 300];

Row[{op, op /. line : Line[__] :> {Thick, Hue[RandomReal[]], line}}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

**Use `Dynamic` in `PlotStyle` options setting:**

```
Show[Histogram[r, Automatic, "PDF"], 
 Plot[Evaluate[Tooltip[PDF[#, x], #]], {x, -3, 3}, 
    PlotStyle -> Dynamic[Directive[{Thick, Hue[RandomReal[]]}]]] & /@ custom, ImageSize -> 300]
(* similar picture *)
```

Comment: Thanks, The second works good,   
What about legend and line style?

Comment: @Momo, please see the update re legends.