# InterplationOrder, ListPlot3D and using AbsoluteOption to find value used. Slow using InterpolationOrder

Tags: options, plotting

What lead to this, is when I noticed that `ListPlot3D` was much slower when adding a specific `InterpolationOrder->n` vs. not and letting the default take care of it.

To find out why it is so much slower (timing is below), I asked Mathematica to tell me what default `InterpolationOrder` it used for the current plot. So I used the command

```
      AbsoluteOptions[p, InterpolationOrder]
```

To do that, which supposed to return the value used in p. From the excellent book `Mathematica Navigator`:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But Mathematica gave an error and said that `InterpolationOrder is not a known option for` this plot. But http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot3D.html shows it there.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So my question is, how does one find what `InterpolationOrder` is used for current plot of `ListPlot3D`?

My sub question is actually (the reason why I wanted to find the above), is why ListPlot3D slows down so much when specifying this option vs. not?  Here is the MWE

```
Clear[x, y, z];
nElem = 10; h = 1/(nElem - 1);
grid = N@Table[{i*h, j*h}, {i, -10, 10, h}, {j, -10, 10, h}];
f[x_, y_] := Sin[x*10 y] Exp[-x y];
force = Map[f[#[[1]], #[[2]]] &, grid, {2}];
p = ListPlot3D[force, InterpolationOrder -> 1, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 AbsoluteOptions[p, InterpolationOrder]
 (*error*)

 Timing[ListPlot3D[force, InterpolationOrder -> 1, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]]
   (*5.647236*)

 Timing[ListPlot3D[force, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]]
     (* 0.624004 *)
```

And as an extra reward, if you can answer how can one use  `InterpolationOrder -> 1` and still have fast plot, I will up-vote you 2 times if I can.

Version 10.0 on windows 7.

Comment: Do I understand that your question can be summarized as:  Why is using `InterpolationOrder -> 1` slower than using the default option `InterpolationOrder -> None`?  Is it really surprising that using interpolation is slower?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, but this is one part of it. The other part is why I get an error when query this option? I did not want to split this to 2 questions. But may be I should have. What do you think? Should they be separate? I can do that. ps. the slow down is really large as can be seen by the numbers. A bit of slow down ok, but 10 times slower?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that `AbsoluteOptions[p, InterpolationOrder]` doesn't work is that `p` is a `Graphics` object and `InterpolationOrder` is an option for (e.g.) `ListPlot3D`, *not* `Graphics`.  `InterpolationOrder` guides the creation of the graphic but it does not remain a mutable part of it.  I addressed this topic here:

- [Is it possible to change the color of plot in Show?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17250/is-it-possible-to-change-the-color-of-plot-in-show/17270#17270)

As to the second question we can easily show that using interpolation plots many more points that if we do not, so it is not surprising that this takes considerably longer:

```
ListPlot3D[force, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}][[1, 1]] // Length
ListPlot3D[force, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, InterpolationOrder -> 1][[1, 1]] // Length
```

> ```
> 41473
>
> 325306
> ```

Comment: I see. So none of options such as `PlotStyle` used can be queried using `AbsoluteOptions`. Just tried it on normal plot: `p0 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red];
AbsoluteOptions[p0, PlotStyle]` and this also gave an error.  This makes `AbsoluteOptions` not as useful as I thought before. May be this is what the book means by "special options" in the screen shot I posted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is a curious thing, the default appears to do a linear interpolation ( ie. rendering more points than input ), yet specifying `InterpolationOrder->1` dramatically increases the number of interpolation points:

simple example:

```
 data = Table[ Sin[x] , {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}] // N;
 ListPlot3D[data]
```

[image]

```
 in = ListPlot[ data[[All, 1]] , PlotStyle -> {PointSize[.02], Red}];
 GraphicsRow[Show[{ListPlot[#[[2 ;; 3]] & /@
     Select[  Cases[ ListPlot3D[data, InterpolationOrder -> #],
        x_List /; Length[x] > 4 , Infinity][[1]] ,
           #[[1]] == 1 & ] ], in}] & /@ {None, 1, 2}]
```

[image]

note the number of points for `Interpolation->1` is the same as for `->2` (and higher)