# Paralleizing the Plot function internally

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning, parallelization

I have a function of several parameters, funct(a,b,c,d,f,...). Mathematica deals with this function fine but it takes a minute or so to make a data point. I want to plot graphs of funct using code like

```
Plot[
    {
    funct(a1,b,c,d,x,...),
    funct(a2,b,c,d,x,...),
    funct(a3,b,c,d,x,...)
    },  
    {x, -10, 10}, PlotPoints -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 3}, ect..
]
```

Again, Mathematica has no problem doing this but it takes an Age. I want to make Plot deal with the plot points in parallel, or perhaps each curve in parallel, and then combine them into a single plot to speed up the process. Is this possible?

ps. I can think of a work around using something like Show[Parallize@Table[Plot[... but that is parallizing the Table function, I would like to know if I can do it all in Plot if possible.

Comment: Hi @ChrisRochester, probably if you share the code of your function we can actually offer and benchmark performance of different solutions.

Comment: I think your workaround `Show@ParallelTable[Plot[...],...]` is a good choice since `Plot` doesn't have parallelization itself.

Comment: @ChrisRochester, please consider taking the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) so you learn the basic rules of the site. Once you gain enough reputation by making [good questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) you will be able help asigning reputation by voting up and down both questions and answers. [Your question has been answered](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), if its answered to satisfaction, then consider [accepting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the best one for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`ParallelCombine`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ParallelCombine.html) for this task:

```
plot = Plot[#, {x, -10, 10}, PlotPoints -> 10] &;

funcs = {Sin[x], Cos[x], Sinc[x]};

g = ParallelCombine[plot, funcs, Show]
```

[image]

Be aware that the expressions in `funcs` are not held in this example.  Consider using Formal Symbols for the plot variables.

You can add styling with [post-processing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17270/121), e.g.:

```
restylePlot[g, {Red, Black, Blue}]
```

[image]

(See the link above for code for `restylePlot`.)

Answer (score 4):

`Plot` by itself is not parallelizable using [`Parallelize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Parallelize.html).

You can plot each curve in a different kernel using [`ParallelTable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelTable.html) and then [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html) the results together

```
Show[
 ParallelTable[
  Plot[
   Sin[a x]
   , {x, 0, Pi}
   , PlotRange -> {-1, 1}
   ], {a, {1, 2, 3}}]]
```

You may need to use [`DistributeDefinitions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistributeDefinitions.html) so the sub-kernels know the definitions of your custom functions.

Otherwise you could calculate the points into a table and then use [`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html)

```
ListPlot[
 ParallelTable[
  {x, Sin[a x]}
  , {a, {1, 2, 3}}
  , {x, 0, Pi, Pi/100}
  ]
 , Joined -> True
 ]
```

You could also try [speeding up](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/TimeMeasurementAndOptimization.html) your function by using [`Compile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Compile.html) , or pre-calculating the parts of it or by using [memoization](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html) or coarse numerical approximation with [`N`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html)

If you share the code of your function we could test further.