# How can I modify text in a Graphics produced by Plot?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have a Plot in a cell of a Mathematica notebook. The Plot was made with data that I no longer have. I want to modify the label of one of the axes, without running the plot command again (since I don't have the data). How can I do this?

Comment: If you put the marker after the plot and write `// InputForm` and then evaluate, it should give you a `Graphics` expression that you can modify.

Comment: Proposed duplicate: [(17250)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17250/121)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Show` to change options in existing graphics.

```
plot = Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,10}, AxesLabel -> {x,y}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Show[plot, AxesLabel -> {x, Sin[x]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Modifying the actual contents is more difficult and involves examining the contents of the `Graphics` expression.