# Show list of plots. How to color them differently?

Tags: plotting

I have a list of plot generated in loop using

```
z = List[];
For[i = 0, i < 10, i++,
  (
    a = Plot[(x + i)^2, {x, -10, 10}]; 
   AppendTo[z, a]
   )];
Show[z]
```

I would like to make the Show command use different color for each plot, how can I do this?

If relevant, that's not really my function generating the plot. I have a complicated procedure generating some data points which I plot using ListPlot with a joined line.

```
a = ListPlot[data, Joined -> True];
```

Comment: Taken at face value this question is a duplicate of [(17250)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17250/121).  The work-around, `PlotStyle` is in my opinion "easily found in the documentation."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
z = List[];
For[i = 0, i < 10, i++,
  (
    a = Plot[(x + i)^2, {x, -10, 10}, PlotStyle -> ColorData[97, i + 1]];
   AppendTo[z, a]
   )];
Show[z]
```

[image]

Alternatively

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[(x + i)^2, {i, 0, 9}], {x, -10, 10},
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, 106}]
```

and with lists

```
ListLinePlot[Table[{x, (x + i)^2}, {i, 0, 9}, {x, -10, 10, 0.1}],
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, 106}]
```

Comment: I'd +1 but left For+AppendTo holds me :P I know it is not part of the question but still.

Comment: @Kuba I often like to add in the minimum necessary to make the OP's code work, to show what was missing.  Proper rewrites don't show that, as you can see by the alternate versions.

Answer (score 5):

```
Show @@ Table[Plot[(x + i)^2, {x, -10, 10},
   PlotStyle -> {Black, Red, Green, Blue}[[i + 1]]], {i, 0, 3}]
```

[image]

To add a legend:

```
colors = {Black, Red, Green, Blue};

Row[{
  Show @@ Table[Plot[(x + i)^2, {x, -10, 10},
     ImageSize -> 400,
     PlotStyle -> colors[[i + 1]]],
    {i, 0, 3}],
  SwatchLegend[colors, "i = " <> ToString@# & /@ Range[0, 3]]
  }]
```

[image]

You can also employ `ListLinePlot`

```
ListLinePlot[Table[{x, (x + i)^2}, {i, 0, 10, 2}, {x, -10, 10, 1}],
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {Automatic, 10^2}},
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic,
 PlotLegends -> Range[0, 10, 2]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
fs = Array[Function[x, (x + #)^2] &, 10, 0]
Plot[Evaluate[#[x] & /@ fs], {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, 106}]
```

Answer (score 3):

If the graphics a generated somewhere where you cannot get access to, then you can try to guess the color to replace and do this:

```
colorguess = ColorData[97][1];
Show[MapIndexed[{v, k} \[Function] (v /. colorguess -> ColorData[97][k[[1]]]), z]]
```

[image]

And as [kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba) mentioned, it is far better to generate your data `z` with the `Table` command. `For` and `AppendTo` are nasty things to use...

Answer (score 1):

A variation using `MapThread` and `Tooltip`:

```
SeedRandom[1];
n = 5;
labels = RandomWord["Noun", n];
MapThread[
  Plot[Tooltip[(x + #1)^2, #3]
    , {x, -10, 10}
    , PlotStyle -> #2
    , PlotLegends -> Placed[SwatchLegend[{#2}, {#3}]
      , After
      ]
    ] &
  , {Range[0, n - 1], RandomColor[n], labels}
  ] // Show
```

---

[image]