# PlotMarkers in Mathematica with using an iteration scheme

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics, mathematical-optimization, legending

I have the following operator $T:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ by $Tx=\frac{x}{2}$. I use the following method for two different initial point $x_{0}\in[0,1]$ as $x_{n+1}=Tx_{n}$ $n=0,1,2,3,...$
I have set the following codes in mathemtica for $x_{0}=0.1$ and $x_{0}=0.9$ as

```
Clear[x, T, a, b, c]
T[x_] := T[x] = (x/2)
x[0] = 0.1;
x[n_] := x[n] = T[x[n - 1]]
NumberForm[a1 = {Table[x[i], {i, 0, 6}]}, 4]
```

The plot code is for this I used

```
plot1 = ListPlot[a1, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

Now for the secod initial Point

```
Clear[x, T, a, b, c]
T[x_] := T[x] = (x/2)
x[0] = 0.1;
x[n_] := x[n] = T[x[n - 1]]
NumberForm[a1 = {Table[x[i], {i, 0, 6}]}, 4]
```

The plot code is for this I used

```
Clear[x, T, a, b, c]
[x_] := T[x] = (x/2)
x[0] = 0.9;
x[n_] := x[n] = T[x[n - 1]]
NumberForm[a2 = {Table[x[i], {i, 0, 6}]}, 4]
```

And plotting these vales as:

```
plot2 = ListPlot[a2, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Blue]
```

I have combined these two plots as:

```
Show[plot1, plot2, PlotRange -> Automatic, Frame -> {{True, True}, {True, True}},FrameLabel -> {Style["Number of iterates", Black, Small],Style["Absolute error", Black, Small]},Epilog->Inset[LineLegend[{Red, Blue, Cyan}, {"x0=0.1", "x0=0.9"}], {5,0.4}]]
```

I get the following attached graph [image]. But I need a graph and legend Plotmarker like  https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWX9u.jpg this full post is at [Show[List of plot] how to color them differently?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/149665/showlist-of-plot-how-to-color-them-differently)

Comment: Dear @Michael I need PlotMarkers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear[x, T]
T[x_] := T[x] = (x/2)
x[0] = 0.1;
x[n_] := x[n] = T[x[n - 1]]
NumberForm[a1 = Table[x[i], {i, 0, 6}], 4]
```

[image]

```
Clear[x, T]
T[x_] := T[x] = (x/2)
x[0] = 0.9;
x[n_] := x[n] = T[x[n - 1]]
NumberForm[a2 = Table[x[i], {i, 0, 6}], 4]
```

[image]

```
ListLinePlot[{a1, a2},
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue},
 PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 8},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {Style["Number of iterates", Black, Small], 
   Style["Absolute error", Black, Small]},
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[
   StringForm["`` = ``", Subscript[x, 0], #] & /@ {0.1, 0.9}, {5/7, 
    2/3}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Dear @Bob I have got what I need. Thanks Again

Comment: @Junaid since you tested the code and said that it works, it's a simple task to upvote and/or accept the answer, and also a matter of politeness. I am just sharing a thought here, since you have not accepted any answers to any of your questions.

Comment: Dear @Bob can you provide me a code for dashing?

Comment: Use `PlotStyle -> {{Red, Dashed}, {Blue, Dotted}}` Also see the documentation for `Dashing`, `AbsoluteDashing`, and  `DotDashed`

Comment: I got the desired aims. Thanks dear @Bob Hanlon