# Offset plot in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, coordinate-transformation

I have a figure obtained from `ParametricPlot`, which is relatively costly to obtain.

For example:

[image]

I would like to offset the picture in terms of a parameter, for example `x1`, so that the figure is drawn at `(x1, 0)` instead of at `(0, 0)`. In other words, I would like to apply a transformation consisting of a slide over the X axis.

I have tried with `Translate` and `GeometricTransformation` but it does not seem to work on plot outputs.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please, post your code to get help. Meanwhile, just add a constant $x_1$ to your $f_x$ component in ParametricPlot.

Comment: related, not sure if duplicate:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17250/9490

Comment: Recalculating the figure using `ParametricPlot` is not an option, it is too much time consuming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the output of your plot, and you want to modify the coordinates without replotting. You can do this easily when you realize the output from any `Plot` function will be a `Graphics` object that you can manipulate like any other expression.

For this case, we can use `ReplaceAll` to replace any coordinate pair of real numbers with a transformed version of it.

```
plot = RegionPlot[
   x^2 + y^3 < 2 && x + y < 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}];
tfunc = TranslationTransform[{5, 5}];
plot2 = Show[
   plot /. pt : {x_Real, y_Real} :> tfunc@pt, 
   PlotRange -> {{3, 7}, {3, 7}}
   ];
{plot, plot2}
```

[image]

`ReplaceAll` is a blunt instrument, it replaces any occurrence of its pattern, so this could lead to unwanted side effects by replacing pairs of real numbers that don't represent a coordinate pair.  But in most cases this works fine.

Comment: Since `ParametricPlot[]`, `RegionPlot[]`, and ilk produce a `GraphicsComplex[]` object, the safe way is to apply your transformations to that, e.g. `Show[plot /. GraphicsComplex[pts_, rest__] :> GraphicsComplex[TranslationTransform[{5, 5}][pts], rest], PlotRange -> {{3, 7}, {3, 7}}]`

Comment: Thank you for this excellent solution!