# How to add colors and legends to plots with "Show"

Tags: plotting, graphics, legending

I have lets say three plots A, B, C. I know that in order to plot them on top of each other I can use `Show` function and it will show them all together, 
Is there a way to change the color (and/or legend) of the plots within the `Show` command? without going back to the original `Plot` for each A, B and C and changing the color and legend.

I tried something like this

```
Show[{A, PlotStyle -> Black}, {B, PlotStyle -> Red}, {C, PlotRange -> Pink}]
```

But i got an error 
(Show::gcomb: Could not combine the graphics objects in ).

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Put PlotStyle -> correspondingstyle as option in each plot, and then use Show[A,B,C]

Comment: @Fraccalo while this is what I would have suggested as well, I think that Erf does not want to go back to the individual plots and if I understand the solution has to be at the level of Show

Comment: That is true @Darth_Bane , I don't want to go back to the each plot,

Comment: sorry didn't read properly, see answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Is this something that you had in mind?

Generate a random plot

```
A = Plot[x^3, {x, -3, 3}]
```

And then

```
Show[A /. _RGBColor -> Red]
```

The above is the simplest resolution I know off and I have used in the past. I found this answer on this site. I am giving [the link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17250/how-to-change-plot-style-or-other-options-after-it-was-created), where you can also find more sophisticated approaches you can check

Regarding the question at the comment: is the following acceptable?

```
Legended[Show[A /. _RGBColor -> Red], Placed[SwatchLegend[{Red, Green, Blue}, 
    {"something"}], {1, 1}]]
```

Comment: the problem with this approach is that it changes all the colors: say for example your plot is: a = Plot[x, {x, 0, 2}, AxesStyle -> Green]; with your code the axes color would be overwritten to Red

Comment: @Fraccalo that is a valid point. I did not know that because I don't change the colours of the axes. Thanks for pointing it out anyway

Comment: @Darth_Bane thank you, this actually works. But do you know how to add legends in similar way ?

Comment: @Erf I just want to point out that the other answer is better and more precise and I have voted for it. Just to be clear

Comment: @Erf while I still suggest that you try the other answer as it is more complete, I think I have answered the PlotLegends comment. please have a look

Answer (score 1):

```
a = Plot[x, {x, 0, 2}];
b = Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 2}];
c = Plot[x^3, {x, 0, 2}];

defaultMMAcolor=RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798]

Show[a /. {defaultMMAcolor -> Black}, 
 b /. {defaultMMAcolor -> Red}, 
 c /. {defaultMMAcolor -> Pink}]
```

> [image]