# Extracting PlotRange versus PlotStyle

Tags: plotting

Why does

```
AbsoluteOptions[
 Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotRange -> Automatic, 
 PlotStyle -> Red], 
 PlotRange]
```

(properly) return `{PlotRange -> {{0., 6.28319}, {-1., 1.}}}`

but

```
AbsoluteOptions[
 Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotRange -> Automatic, 
 PlotStyle -> Red], 
 PlotStyle]
```

not return the `Red`?

Comment: related: [How to change plot style or other options after it was created](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17270/125)

Comment: `Options[Plot[....], opts]` and `AbsoluteOptions[Plot[...], opts]` work only for `opts` that are options for `Graphics` (`PlotStyle` , `ColorFunction`, `MeshFunctions`,  `Mesh`, `RegionFunction` etc are options for `Plot` but not for `Graphics`.)

Comment: OK.  Thanks........